# Problem in removing hardcoded values using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all Wish u all Happy New Year. I have a problem in writing query. While executing my query I am getting an error.

Query:

```
select case 

when S.R1 = '6' then 5

when S.R1 =  '7' then 6

when S.R1 = '8' then 7

when S.R1 = '9' then 8

when S.R1 ='10' then 9 

else S.R1 end as Q

FROM [HelpService].[dbo].[help] s
-----------------------------------------------

SELECT [Source], [Score] 

INTO #Temp_Q

FROM [HelpDesk].[dbo].[Survey] 

WHERE [data_Source Name] = 'Text Data'

-----------------------------------------------

select CONVERT(REAL, a.[Dell Score]) as Q

FROM [HelpService].[dbo].[help] s

LEFT OUTER JOIN #CE_Temp_Q a on

s.[R1] = a.[Source]
```

ERROR

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1

Error converting data type varchar to real.

What I am asked to do is I need to remove the hard coded values and need to write queries with a temp table.

Thanks in Advance,
Shashra

Comment: Not enough information. What is the connection between your 2 queries? Which one gives the error? What are the schemas of your tables?

Comment: If the error is in the first select add where isnumeric(s.r1) =1 to your first query

Comment: @u07ch - That isn't guaranteed to solve the problem SQL Server is free to do the convert first and the filter later as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088709/what-is-query-execution-doing-to-this-query-in-sql-server-2005/3088835#3088835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error converting data type varchar to real

This means one of your values contains somthing that isn't a Number.

For example the following works fine

```
SELECT convert(Real, '1')
UNION SELECT convert(Real, ' ')
UNION SELECT convert(Real, NULL)
UNION SELECT convert(Real, '123.123')
UNION SELECT convert(Real, '   456  ')
```

​
But either of the following will yield the same error you are getting

```
SELECT convert(Real, '   456  ')


SELECT CONVERT(Real, '1 2')
```

**UPDATE**

Sometimes its not so obvious what the problem values are

Try the following to find it

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.[Dell Score]
FROM 
      [HelpService].[dbo].[help] s
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #CE_Temp_Q a on
      s.[R1] = a.[Source]
```

OR

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.[Dell Score],
        DATALENGTH (a.[Dell Score])
  FROM 
      [HelpService].[dbo].[help] s
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #CE_Temp_Q a on
      s.[R1] = a.[Source]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me.. But I just checked that all the values comming to [DELL SCORE] are just 'integers' (1,2,3,4) and NULL's means ("NULL").

Comment: @Shahsra I've updated the answer. This should help identify the problem values. BTW I'm not sure what is meant by NULL's means ("NULL"). Are you trying to convert the literal 4 character string "NULL" to a real. Because that can't be converted to a real anymore than CONVERT(Real, 'Shahsra') can.

Answer (score 1):

What does the following query return?

```
select a.[Dell Score]
FROM [HelpService].[dbo].[help] s
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CE_Temp_Q a on
s.[R1] = a.[Source] 
WHERE  a.[Dell Score] like '%[^0-9.]%'
```