# Getting Error while executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error while eleminating the hard coded values.

Instead of this case statement I need to write simple select statement...using temp tables...

```
select case [BVG]
   when 1 then 1
   when 2 then 2
   when 3 then 3
end as Q0,

SELECT  CASE [AVG]
   when 1 then 1
   when 1.33 then 2
   when 1.5  then 2
   when 1.67 then 3
   when 2 then 3
   when 2.33 then 4
End as Q

FROM [MS].[BE].[Survey]
```

So I have written a code using temp table.....

```
SELECT [Source], [Score] 

INTO #Temp_Table

FROM [MS].[dbo].[S_Survey]

WHERE [data_Source] = 'USA'
```

Instead of that case statement I am replacing this select statement....

```
SELECT  q.[Score] as Q --- Getting error in this place.Data Type is varchar (100).

FROM [MS].[BE].[Survey] s

LEFT OUTER JOIN #Temp_Table q on

s.[AVG] = q.[Source]
```

But I am getting an error while executing.... And the error is

> **Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>       Error converting data type varchar to float.**

Instead of that place near `q.[score] as Q` what can I write.... and how can I write the syntax...

Thanks,
Sahsra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't average varchars.

Try this

```
SELECT [Source] , cast( [Score] as decimal (10,2) )--or whatever you need it to be

INTO #Temp_Table

FROM [MS].[dbo].[S_Survey]

WHERE [data_Source] = 'USA'
```

Comment: [AVG] is the field name not the use of the Aggregate, so I don't think "You can't average varchars" applies here.

Comment: Thanks for giving me reply. But there is a problem if we put decimal....Becuase there is a single value 'NULL' in that column. If we put decimal it wont accept the 'NULL'...So what shall I do now...

Comment: [AVG] column is just a name they took...they are not aggregating anything there....

Comment: You should not be using 'Null' but NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `s.AVG` is a float and `q.Source` isn't. This would cause SQL Server to do an implicit conversion on the JOIN `ON s.[AVG] = q.[Source]`and one of your values isn't a character. You should take another look at either [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572428/problem-in-removing-hardcoded-values-using-temp-table/4572602#4572602) or 
[Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513811/martin) the last time you had this problem.

e.g.

```
SELECT  q.[Score] 
FROM [MS].[BE].[Survey] s
WHERE like Score '%[^0-9.]%'
```

**UPDATE** If you need to remove the four character value 'NULL' you could probably do the following (haven't tested)

```
SELECT  q.[Score] as Q --- Getting error in this place.Data Type is varchar (100).

FROM [MS].[BE].[Survey] s

LEFT OUTER JOIN #Temp_Table q on

s.[AVG] = q.[Source]
and q.[Source] <> 'NULL'
```

Or you could not insert them into the #Temp_Table to begin with.

Or you could delete those values before you try and JOIN.

Of course this makes me think why aren't you using a Numerical type on the #temp_table to begin with?

Comment: Hi thanks for reminding me but I have already tried its not working in my case.... Because there are some values containing 'NULL' and some are 1,2,3 and some are 1.1,2.33,2.54 like this....

Comment: "<> 'NULL'" doesn't look right. It should be 'IS NOT NULL' (unless the actual value is 'null', which is bad design).

Comment: @IanC Its the bad design one hence my explanation " If you need to remove the four character value 'NULL"

Comment: I know... my comment was to the OP, not you :-)