# Order Of Execution of the SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am confused with the order of execution of this query, please explain me this.
I am confused with when the join is applied, function is called, a new column is added with the Case and when the serial number is added. Please explain the order of  execution of all this.

```
select Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'Serial Number', 
    EP.FirstName,Ep.LastName,[dbo].[GetBookingRoleName](ES.UserId,EP.BookingRole) as RoleName,  
    (select top 1 convert(varchar(10),eventDate,103)from [3rdi_EventDates] where EventId=13) as EventDate,
    (CASE [dbo].[GetBookingRoleName](ES.UserId,EP.BookingRole)  
            WHEN    '90 Day Client' THEN 'DC'
            WHEN    'Association Client'  THEN  'DC'
            WHEN    'Autism Whisperer'    THEN  'DC'
            WHEN    'CampII'             THEN   'AD' 
            WHEN    'Captain'              THEN 'AD' 
            WHEN    'Chiropractic Assistant' THEN 'AD'
            WHEN    'Coaches'               THEN 'AD'
            END) as Category from [3rdi_EventParticipants] as EP  
    inner join [3rdi_EventSignup] as ES on EP.SignUpId = ES.SignUpId  
    where EP.EventId = 13
    and userid in (  
    select distinct userid from userroles  
    --where roleid not in(6,7,61,64) and roleid not in(1,2))  
    where roleid not in(19, 20, 21, 22) and roleid not in(1,2))
```

This is the function which is called from the above query.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GetBookingRoleName]  
(  
 @UserId as integer,
 @BookingId as integer
)  
RETURNS varchar(20)  
as  
begin  
declare @RoleName varchar(20)  

if @BookingId = -1
Select Top 1 @RoleName=R.RoleName From UserRoles UR inner join Roles R on UR.RoleId=R.RoleId Where UR.UserId=@UserId and R.RoleId not in(1,2)  
else
Select @RoleName= RoleName From Roles where RoleId = @BookingId

return @RoleName  
end
```

Comment: Off topic but you will likely be much better off ditching that UDF and making the logic inline.

Comment: As of 2022, Wikipedia has a nice article on [SQL Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax#Queries) that tackles that (_i.e._, SQL execution order) at some point (Queries section).

Comment: SQLite https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/328178/what-is-the-evaluation-clause-order-in-sqlite

Answer (score 70, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language. The result of a query must be what you would get if you evaluated as follows (from Microsoft):

> [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)
>
> The following steps show the logical
> processing order, or binding order,
> for a SELECT statement. This order
> determines when the objects defined in
> one step are made available to the
> clauses in subsequent steps. For
> example, if the query processor can
> bind to (access) the tables or views
> defined in the FROM clause, these
> objects and their columns are made
> available to all subsequent steps.
> Conversely, because the SELECT clause
> is step 8, any column aliases or
> derived columns defined in that clause
> cannot be referenced by preceding
> clauses. However, they can be
> referenced by subsequent clauses such
> as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the
> actual physical execution of the
> statement is determined by the query
> processor and the order may vary from
> this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

The optimizer is free to choose any order it feels appropriate to produce the best execution time. Given any SQL query, is basically impossible to anybody to pretend it knows the execution order. If you add detailed information about the schema involved (exact tables and indexes definition) and the estimated cardinalities (size of data and selectivity of keys) then one can take a *guess* at the probable execution order.

Ultimately, the only correct 'order' is the one described ion the actual execution plan. See [Displaying Execution Plans by Using SQL Server Profiler Event Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190233.aspx) and [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx).

A completely different thing though is how do queries, subqueries and expressions project themselves into 'validity'. For instance if you have an aliased expression in the SELECT projection list, can you use the alias in the WHERE clause? Like this:

```
SELECT a+b as c
FROM t
WHERE c=...;
```

Is the use of `c` alias valid in the where clause? The answer is NO. Queries form a syntax tree, and a lower branch of the tree cannot be reference something defined higher in the tree. This is not necessarily an order of 'execution', is more of a syntax parsing issue. It is equivalent to writing this code in C#:

```
void Select (int a, int b)
{
   if (c = ...) then {...}
   int c = a+b;
}
```

Just as in C# this code won't compile because the variable `c` is used before is defined, the SELECT above won't compile properly because the alias `c` is referenced lower in the tree than is actually defined.

Unfortunately, unlike the well known rules of C/C# language parsing, the SQL rules of how the query tree is built are somehow esoteric. There is a brief mention of them in [Single SQL Statement Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190623%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) but a detailed discussion of how they are created, and what order is valid and what not, I don't know of any source. I'm not saying there aren't good sources, I'm sure some of the good SQL books out there cover this topic.

Note that the syntax tree order does not match the visual order of the SQL text. For example the ORDER BY clause is usually the last in the SQL text, but as a syntax tree it sits above everything else (it sorts the *output* of the SELECT, so it sits above the SELECTed columns so to speak) and as such is *is* valid to reference the `c` alias:

```
SELECT a+b as c
FROM t
ORDER BY c;
```

Comment: BUt in my above query when my function is called? after fatching result of join of before that, if before that then where it gets the parameter value from, also when it is executed "(select top 1 convert(varchar(10),eventDate,103)from [3rdi_EventDates] where EventId=13)", and when that case for a new column is executed

Comment: The only way to find that out is to look at the actual execution plan.

Comment: There are *WAY* too many answers around the internet/SO that say "SQL optimizers does it's magicks -- no one can know how a given query will execute". But as you realized lower on, this is not true! Yes, the optimizer does random stuff -- but obviously there is *some* execution order of clauses. Or else, how could you ever depend on a query? Please move your update to the top, so people who are looking for an answer don't see your wrong answer at the top and then leave the thread...

Comment: [All-at-once](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx)

Comment: Can you update this answer to make it more clear for the community? Currently, a user must read a bunch of stuff and then at the bottom it tells you, that stuff wasnt exactly right anyway. Not a great format

Comment: This answer is correct. The actual execution order of a SQL statement is not known in advance. The optimizer will decide how to execute the statement at runtime.

Answer (score 88):

Queries are generally processed in the follow order (SQL Server). I have no idea if other RDBMS's do it this way.

```
FROM [MyTable]
    ON [MyCondition]
  JOIN [MyJoinedTable]
 WHERE [...]
 GROUP BY [...]
HAVING [...]
SELECT [...]
 ORDER BY [...]
```

Comment: Yes the answer marked as correct mislead a little bit

Comment: it would probably have gotten more upvotes if it had referenced an authoritative source

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @littleO This answer describes a good way of understanding what the database could do to execute the query; this is useful as a **pedagogical tool**, so new students can understand SQL more easily. However, SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one like C, Java, Python, etc. This means real world, production databases are free to rephrase the query, rewrite it, turn it inside out, and execute it in any order. Only a naive database will execute the query as this answer explains; any medium-grade to high end database will use all kinds of dirty tricks to make the query blazing fast.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Fun fact, imperative languages are also somewhat declarative. Take
`int a = 2; int b = 4*23-12+a;` one would think that the compiled binary would do the multiplication and additions when executed, but nah, the compiler is going to solve all the arithmetic and the binary will just contain b = 82 hardcoded.

Answer (score 13):

SQL query is not imperative but declarative, so you have no idea which the statement is executed first, but since SQL is evaluated by SQL query engines, most of the SQL engines follows similar process to obtain the results. You may have to understand how the query engine works internally to understand some SQL execution behavior.

Julia Evens has a great post explaining this, it is worth to check it out:

https://jvns.ca/blog/2019/10/03/sql-queries-don-t-start-with-select/

[image]

Answer (score 9):

SQL is a declarative language, meaning that it tells the SQL engine what to do, not how. This is in contrast to an imperative language such as C, in which how to do something is clearly laid out.

This means that not all statements will execute as expected. Of particular note are boolean expressions, which may not evaluate from left-to-right as written. For example, the following code is not guaranteed to execute without a divide by zero error:

```
SELECT 'null' WHERE 1 = 1 OR 1 / 0 = 0
```

The reason for this is the query optimizer chooses the best (most efficient) way to execute a statement. This means that, for example, a value may be loaded and filtered before a transforming predicate is applied, causing an error. See the second link above for an example

See: [here](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088709/what-is-query-execution-doing-to-this-query-in-sql-server-2005/).

Answer (score 4):

"Order of execution" is probably a bad mental model for SQL queries. Its hard to actually write a single query that would actually depend on order of execution (this is a good thing). Instead you should think of all join and where clauses happening simultaneously (almost like a template)

That said you could run display the [Execution Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) which should give you insight into it.

However since its's not clear why you want to know the order of execution, I'm guessing your trying to get a mental model for this query so you can fix it in some way. This is how I would "translate" your query, although I've done well with this kind of analysis there's some grey area with how precise it is.

FROM AND WHERE CLAUSE

- Give me all the Event Participants rows. `from [3rdi_EventParticipants`
- Also give me all the Event Signup rows that match the Event Participants rows on SignUpID `inner join 3rdi_EventSignup] as ES on EP.SignUpId = ES.SignUpId`
- But Only for Event 13 `EP.EventId = 13`
- And only if the user id has a record in the user roles table where the role id is not in 1,2,19,20,21,22
  `userid in (

  select distinct userid from userroles

  --where roleid not in(6,7,61,64) and roleid not in(1,2))

  where roleid not in(19, 20, 21, 22) and roleid not in(1,2))`

SELECT CLAUSE

- For each of the rows give me a unique ID 
  `Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'Serial Number',`
- The participants First Name `EP.FirstName`
- The participants Last Name `Ep.LastName`
- The Booking Role name `GetBookingRoleName`
- Go look in the Event Dates and find out what the first eventDate where the EventId = 13 that you find
  `(select top 1 convert(varchar(10),eventDate,103)from [3rdi_EventDates] where EventId=13) as EventDate`
- Finally translate the GetBookingRoleName in Category. I don't have a table for this so I'll map it manually `(CASE [dbo].[GetBookingRoleName](ES.UserId,EP.BookingRole)

          WHEN    '90 Day Client' THEN 'DC'
          WHEN    'Association Client'  THEN  'DC'
          WHEN    'Autism Whisperer'    THEN  'DC'
          WHEN    'CampII'             THEN   'AD' 
          WHEN    'Captain'              THEN 'AD' 
          WHEN    'Chiropractic Assistant' THEN 'AD'
          WHEN    'Coaches'               THEN 'AD'
          END) as Category`

So a couple of notes here. You're not ordering by anything when you select TOP. You should probably have na order by there. You could also just as easily put that in your from clause e.g.

```
from [3rdi_EventParticipants] as EP  
    inner join [3rdi_EventSignup] as ES on EP.SignUpId = ES.SignUpId,   
       (select top 1 convert(varchar(10),eventDate,103)
       from [3rdi_EventDates] where EventId=13
       Order by eventDate) dates
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a *logical* order to evaluation of the query text, but the database engine can choose what order execute the query components based upon what is most optimal. The logical text parsing ordering is listed below. That is, for example, why you can't use an alias from `SELECT` clause in a `WHERE` clause. As far as the query parsing process is concerned, the alias doesn't exist yet.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

See [the Microsoft documentation (see "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified order for T-SQL -> SELECT statement:

```
1) FROM 
2) Cartesian product
3) ON
4) Outer rows
5) WHERE
6) GROUP BY
7) HAVING
8) SELECT
9) Evaluation phase in SELECT 
10) DISTINCT
11) ORDER BY
12) TOP
```

as I had done so far - same order was applicable in SQLite.

Source => [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

... of course there are (rare) exceptions.

Comment: What does this answer add to to this old question more than the other answers already provided?

Comment: Ads #2, #9, SQLite. While not extensive addition - it might help save few searches.