# Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, left-join

I am trying to get the following to return a count for every organization using a left join in PostgreSQL, but I cannot figure out why it's not working:

```
  select o.name as organisation_name,
         coalesce(COUNT(exam_items.id)) as total_used
  from organisations o
  left join exam_items e on o.id = e.organisation_id
  where e.item_template_id = #{sanitize(item_template_id)}
  and e.used = true
  group by o.name
  order by o.name
```

Using `coalesce` doesn't seem to work. I'm at my wit's end! Any help would certainly be appreciated!

To clarify what's not working, at the moment the query only returns values for organisations that have a count greater than 0. I would like it to return a line for **every** organisation, regardless of the count.

Table definitions:

```
TABLE exam_items
  id serial NOT NULL
  exam_id integer
  item_version_id integer
  used boolean DEFAULT false
  question_identifier character varying(255)
  organisation_id integer
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  item_template_id integer
  stem_id integer
  CONSTRAINT exam_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)

TABLE organisations
  id serial NOT NULL
  slug character varying(255)
  name character varying(255)
  code character varying(255)
  address text
  organisation_type integer
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
  super boolean DEFAULT false
  CONSTRAINT organisations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: `coalesce(COUNT(exam_items.id),0) as total_used` ???

Comment: well yeah, I've also tried COUNT(exam_items.id) as total_used, but i have to say sql is not really my forte!

Comment: sorry I see what you mean! I've tried that, but still no luck :/

Comment: When posting a question, please spell out what "it's not working" means within the question - returning nothing, returning an incorrect value, yielding an error, etc.

Comment: thanks, makes perfect sense! however, even by using the line as you suggested, the query still only return the values for the organisations with a count superior to 0 - I wonder if this doesn't have anything to do and exam_items.used = true

Comment: Not relevant, but still important: `organisation_id integer REFERENCES organisations(id)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### Fix the `LEFT JOIN`

This should work:

```sql
SELECT o.name AS organisation_name, count(e.id) AS total_used
FROM   organisations   o
LEFT   JOIN exam_items e ON e.organisation_id = o.id 
                        AND e.item_template_id = #{sanitize(item_template_id)}
                        AND e.used
GROUP  BY o.name
ORDER  BY o.name;
```

You had a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` but the later `WHERE` conditions made it act like a plain `[INNER] JOIN`.
Move the condition(s) to the `JOIN` clause to make it work as intended. This way, only rows that fulfill all these conditions are joined in the first place (or columns from the *right* table are filled with NULL). Like you had it, joined rows are tested for additional conditions virtually *after* the `LEFT JOIN` and removed if they don't pass, just like with a plain `JOIN`.

`count()` never returns NULL to begin with. It's an exception among aggregate functions in this respect. Therefore, <strike>`COALESCE(COUNT(col))`</strike> *never* makes sense, even with additional parameters. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> It should be noted that **except for `count`**, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected.

Bold emphasis mine. See:

- [Count the number of attributes that are NULL for a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444591/count-the-number-of-attributes-that-are-null-for-a-row/31445274#31445274)

`count()` must be on a column defined `NOT NULL` (like `e.id`), or where the join condition guarantees `NOT NULL` (`e.organisation_id`, `e.item_template_id`, or `e.used`) in the example.

Since `used` is type `boolean`, the expression `e.used = true` is noise that burns down to just `e.used`.

Since `o.name` is not defined `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, you may want to `GROUP BY o.id` instead (`id` being the PK) - unless you *intend* to fold rows with the same name (including NULL).

#### Aggregate first, join later

If most or all rows of `exam_items` are counted in the process, this equivalent query is typically considerably faster / cheaper:

```sql
SELECT o.id, o.name AS organisation_name, e.total_used
FROM   organisations o
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT organisation_id AS id   -- alias to simplify join syntax
        , count(*) AS total_used  -- count(*) = fastest to count all
   FROM   exam_items
   WHERE  item_template_id = #{sanitize(item_template_id)}
   AND    used
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e USING (id)
ORDER  BY o.name, o.id;
```

(This is assuming that you don't want to fold rows with the same name like mentioned above - the typical case.)

Now we can use the faster / simpler `count(*)` in the subquery, and we need no `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

See:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

Comment: @wildplasser: That one has been missed by the best. It's a sneaky one.

Comment: I guess, it is basically a style/taste issue. Personally, I would never write such a line (I hope ;-) Just like coalesce() with only one argument makes no sense. And the lack of correlation names / aliases confuses me.

Comment: @wildplasser: I always start by formatting and cleaning up the query, before I even try to understand the heap of text.

Comment: Me, too. Normally. (that's the real reason for my love for CTEs) But in case I *think* I get the issue in one reading pass, I get too trigger happy.

Comment: @mulus He's mine too

Comment: Just in case you are getting 1 instead of 0 for the count: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155025/return-1-instead-of-0-when-count-result-is-null (the column specificied in the count function is important).

Comment: @JCarlosR: I added a note to address that while editing.

Answer (score 15):

To make it clear,

the important line is `GROUP BY MAIN_TABLE` that will handle NULL value from `SOME_TABLE`

```
SELECT COUNT(ST.ID)
FROM MAIN_TABLE MT
LEFT JOIN SOME_TABLE ST ON MT.ID = ST.MT_ID

GROUP BY MT.ID -- this line is a must
```

Comment: Simple & clear 