# Why does null equal integer in WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join

I am doing a query with a trivial join, with the intention of finding the newest record that the user hasn't voted on yet:

```
SELECT
    v.user_id,
    v.version_id,
    vv.user_id
FROM versions v
LEFT JOIN versions_votes vv ON v.version_id = vv.version_id
WHERE vv.user_id != 39;
```

Curiously, this **returns no rows if vv.user_id is null.** My admittedly pedestrian understanding of the problem is that NULL *cannot* be equal to anything - that's why we have to test for `IS NULL` rather than `=NULL` in the first place.

And yet, here we are - and if I modify the WHERE clause as follows:

```
WHERE (vv.user_id != 39 OR vv.user_id IS NULL)
```

the query appears to work properly (and also appears to confirm that `NULL` is evaluating to 39.

Comment: Where do `status` and `created` come from? Please clarify and (always) add your version of Postgres.

Comment: This question may provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null Bottom line <operator> <comparison> <operator> where one of the operators is NULL makes the expression evaluate to FALSE

Comment: I think Bob's got it right here - since I'm doing a != comparison it would react to a NULL on one side in the way he suggests, which i failed to consider.

Comment: `status` and `created` come from `versions`, but aren't relevant - as I said, the query behaves as intended if I test for NULL via OR.

Comment: @sudowned: It is *always* relevant where each and every column comes from. Even if those columns do not seem relevant to you. This *needs* to be clear in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I disagree. The issue was already isolated specifically to the second `AND` clause - I could have omitted mention of those columns entirely from my query and still obtained an accurate answer. If anything, that only indicates that I *should* have removed those columns from the query... which I have now done.

Comment: That works, too. Even if `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` might arouse skeptics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that *"NULL cannot be equal to anything"*.
What you are missing is that [NULL cannot be unequal, either](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

`NULL` compared to anything is always `NULL`. The problem at hand is that you got the `LEFT JOIN` wrong. This should work:

```sql
SELECT v.user_id, v.version_id, vv.user_id
FROM   versions v
LEFT   JOIN versions_votes vv ON v.version_id = vv.version_id
                             AND vv.user_id = 39
WHERE  vv.version_id IS NULL
ORDER  BY v.created
LIMIT  1;
```

You had an additional condition referencing `vv` in the `WHERE` clause: `AND vv.user_id != 39`. Probably expecting that `NULL != 39` would qualify, but it doesn't. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/count-on-left-join-not-returning-0-values/15468034#15468034)

There are basically *three different techniques* to do this:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: @wildplasser: It certainly does.

Comment: Maybe three valued logic was not such a good idea after all. But the downside is: people would implement their own system. Badly. And/or not enforce it consequently.