# LEFT JOIN query with JSON object array aggregate

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables:

Table `person` with columns: `person_id`, `person_name`
Table `pet` with columns: `pet_id`, `owner_id`, `pet_name`

```
person data:
1, 'John'
2, 'Jill'
3, 'Mary'

pet data:
1, 1, 'Fluffy'
2, 1, 'Buster'
3, 2, 'Doggy'
```

How to write a `SELECT` query from `person` left join `pet` on `person_id = owner_id` with aggregate functions so my result data looks like:

```
1, [{pet_id:1,pet_name:'Fluffy'},{pet_id:2,pet_name:'Buster'}], 'John'
2, [{pet_id:3,pet_name:'Doggy'}], 'Jill'
3, [],'Mary'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use **`LEFT JOIN LATERAL`** and aggregate in the subquery:

```sql
SELECT p.person_id, COALESCE(pet.pets, '[]') AS pets, p.person_name
FROM   person p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('pet_id', pet.pet_id
                                   , 'pet_name', pet.pet_name)) AS pets
   FROM   pet
   WHERE  pet.owner_id = p.person_id
   ) pet ON true
ORDER  BY p.person_id;  -- optional, Q suggests ordered results
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b2e0abe822bc614633219ee7a868a56)*

This way you do not need to aggregate results from the outer query. **Simpler** and cleaner when your outer query is more complex than the example in the question. When aggregating multiple related tables, it even becomes a necessity:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)
- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

It is also typically much **faster** when there are selective predicates on the outer table `person` - which is the typical use case.

Make sure there is an **index** on `pet(owner_id)` to make it fast.
Or even one on `pet(owner_id, pet_id, pet_name)` or `pet(owner_id) INCLUDE (pet_id, pet_name)` in Postgres 11 or later, if your row isn't wide like in your example, and if you get index-only scans out of it.

Oh, and use **`json_build_object()`** to preserve attribute *names* for arbitrary selections:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

Related:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: Great explanation! Saved me a lot of time reading through the docs on Lateral joins. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

```
select
    person_id,
    jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(pet) - 'owner_id'),
    person_name
from person
left join pet on person_id = owner_id
group by person_id;

 person_id |                                 jsonb_agg                                  | person_name 
-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
         1 | [{"pet_id": 1, "pet_name": "Fluffy"}, {"pet_id": 2, "pet_name": "Buster"}] | John
         2 | [{"pet_id": 3, "pet_name": "Doggy"}]                                       | Jill
         3 | [null]                                                                     | Mary
(3 rows)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=12013e7d3e30ec0245dfe8767ec23682)

Answer (score 3):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b53f6e1606280681bb2238d094711090)

```
select
    COALESCE(
        json_agg(row_to_json(row(p2.pet_id::text, p2.pet_name))) FILTER (WHERE pet_id IS NOT NULL), 
       '[]'
    ) as json,
    p1.person_name
from person p1
left join pet p2
    on p1.person_id = p2.owner_id
group by
    p1.person_name;
```

1. `FILTER` clause to filter out `NULL` values. That creates a `NULL` value for Mary.
2. If you want to add an empty JSON array: Use `COALESCE`, which replaces `NULL` with a default value

Answer (score 2):

Postgres' built in JSON and aggregation functions can handle your requirement:

```
select
    json_agg(row_to_json(row(p2.pet_id::text, p2.pet_name))) as json,
    p1.person_name
from person p1
left join pet p2
    on p1.person_id = p2.owner_id
group by
    p1.person_name;
```

Comment: @TomBerghuis If you like to get a valid JSON array instead of a simple array, you could use `json_agg()` instead of `array_agg()`

Comment: thanks I'm trying your solution but getting the error SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function json_agg(json, unknown) does not exist¶  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I got array_agg to work, but for the persons with no pets I am getting [{pet_id:null,  pet_name:null}] how to filter this?

Comment: json_agg works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=165d61b08b1e304d5f3f912bfda90f96

Comment: @S-Man how to filter the null value so empty array for Mary

Comment: Filter out the NULL values with `FILTER (WHERE pet_id IS NOT NULL)`. If you want to create an empty array you can use COALESCE https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b53f6e1606280681bb2238d094711090

Answer (score 1):

some lateral query can also be written in correlated subquery.
You want to select some columns from tableA and aggregate info from tableB.
you can use select tableA columns, aggregate function from tableA.

It will work because aggregate functions in this context only generate one row.
Based on Erwin's answer. You can also:

```
SELECT
    p.person_id,
    p.person_name,
    (
        SELECT
            coalesce(json_agg(json_build_object('pet_id', pet.pet_id, 'pet_name', pet_name)), '[]') AS pets
        FROM
            pet
        WHERE
            pet.owner_id = p.person_id)
FROM
    person_p p;
```