# Sum values by id, and update another table with the results

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate

I have two tables:

- Users with ID and Amount_due columns
- Bills with ID, billed_cents, User_Id

I need to sum all the billed_cents in the bills table by ID and update by ID the user's amount_due.

Here is what I am trying so far with no luck

```
UPDATE users
SET amount_due = (SELECT SUM(billed_cents) FROM bills INNER JOIN users ON bills.user_id = users.id WHERE someConditions)
FROM bills
WHERE users.id = bills.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient query depends on undisclosed details. This works in any case:

```sql
UPDATE users u
SET    amount_due = b.sum_cents
FROM   (
   SELECT user_id, sum(billed_cents) AS sum_cents
   FROM   bills
   WHERE  <some conditions>  -- maybe can go here? (better if possible)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b
WHERE  u.id = b.user_id 
-- AND <some conditions>     -- may have to go here?
```

This form does not involve the table `users` (a second time) in the subquery.

For selective filters on `users`, it may be more efficient to add the join back and filter *before* aggregating.

See:

- [Update with subquery referencing the main table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301601/3684)
- [LEFT JOIN query with JSON object array aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267279/left-join-query-with-json-object-array-aggregate/58270121#58270121)
- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)