# Create a JSON object from parent -> child relationship without duplication

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, hierarchical-data, postgresql-performance

I want to query a database, get ALL of the user's data, and send it to my front end in a JSON object (with many layers of nesting).

e.g.

```
{
 user_id: 1,
 username: james,
 messages: [
  {
   message_id: 'fewfef',
   message: 'lorum ipsum'
   ... : {
    ...
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Sample schema/data:

```
--user table (parent)
CREATE TABLE userdata (
    user_id integer,
    username text
);

INSERT INTO userdata VALUES (1, 'james');

-- messages table (child) connected to user table
CREATE TABLE messages(
    message_id integer,
    fk_messages_userdata integer,
    message text
);

INSERT INTO messages VALUES (1, 1, 'hello');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (2, 1, 'lorum ipsum');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (3, 1, 'test123');

-- querying all data at once
SELECT u.username, m.message_id, m.message FROM userdata u
    INNER JOIN messages m
        ON u.user_id = m.fk_messages_userdata
WHERE u.user_id = '1';
```

This outputs the data as so:

```
username|message_id|message    |
--------+----------+-----------+
james   |         1|hello      |
james   |         2|lorum ipsum|
james   |         3|test123    |
```

The issue is I have the username is repeated for each message. For larger databases and more layers of nesting this would cause a lot of useless data being queried/sent.

Is it better to do one query to get all of this data and send it to the backend, or make a seperate query for each table, and only get the data I want?

For example I could run these queries:

```
-- getting only user metadata
SELECT username from userdata WHERE user_id = '1';
-- output
username|
--------+
james   |

-- getting only user's messages
SELECT m.message_id, m.message as message_id FROM userdata u
    INNER JOIN messages m
        ON u.user_id = m.fk_messages_userdata
WHERE u.user_id = '1';
--output
message_id|message_id |
----------+-----------+
         1|hello      |
         2|lorum ipsum|
         3|test123    |
```

This way I get only the data I need, and its a little easier to work with, as it comes to the backed more organized. But is there a disadvantage of running separate queries instead of one big one? Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Joins can produce result rows with duplicate data when relationships with :n multiplicity are involved.  If you want to avoid that then don't perform such joins.  Instead, query each side separately.  JSON is reasonably well suited for representing the resulting multi-level data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it better to do one query to get all of this data and send it to the backend, or make a seperate query for each table, and only get the data I want?

It's best to run only one query and get only the data you want. As long as it doesn't get too complicated - which it doesn't IMO:

```sql
SELECT to_json(usr)
FROM  (
   SELECT u.user_id, u.username
       , (SELECT json_agg(msg)  -- aggregation in correlated subquery
          FROM  (
            SELECT m.message_id, m.message
            FROM   messages m
            WHERE  m.fk_messages_userdata = u.user_id
            ) msg
         ) AS messages
   FROM   userdata u
   WHERE  u.user_id = 1  -- provide user_id here once!
   ) usr;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JiEeoC0D)

There are many other ways.

A `(LEFT) JOIN LATERAL` instead of the correlated subquery. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

`json_build_object()` instead of converting whole rows from subselects. See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [LEFT JOIN query with JSON object array aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267279/left-join-query-with-json-object-array-aggregate/58270121#58270121)

But this version above should be shortest and fastest.

Related:

- [What are the pros and cons of performing calculations in sql vs. in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510092/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-performing-calculations-in-sql-vs-in-your-applica/7518619#7518619)