# Joining Tags as an Array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have this:

```sql
posts
- id
- title
- ...
tags
- pid (fk to posts.id)
- name
```

And I would like to join my posts so that I have an array of tags in my posts record:

```sql
id | title |     | tags
___|_______|_____|_____________________
1  | me    | ... | ["you", "him"]
2  | you   | ... | ["him", "something"]
...
```

How can I accomplish this. I don't want to over fetch, either.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW posts_tags AS
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
JOIN array_agg(
  SELECT tags.name FROM tags
  WHERE posts.id = tags.pid
)
```

Not sure how the array part works in SQL or how to finish this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query with fixed syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   posts p
JOIN  (
   SELECT pid AS id, array_agg(name) AS post_tags
   FROM   tags
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) t USING (id);
```

It's faster to aggregate before you join.

For a small selection of posts, a `LATERAL` subquery, or a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list can be faster. See:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)