# Query to join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to `inner join` two tables. First table can have two records so performing `group by` on that. Error:

> column "b.db" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

```
select distinct a.schemaname,a.tablename,max(a.tbl_cmmt_txt) as 
tbl_cmmt_txt,max(a.cleansed_tbl_cmmt_txt) as cleansed_tbl_cmmt_txt,max(a.tbl_dscr_txt) 
as tbl_dscr_txt,max(a.cleansed_tbl_dscr_txt)as cleansed_tbl_dscr_txt,max(a.tbl_annt_txt) 
as tbl_annt_txt,max(a.cleansed_tbl_annt_txt) as cleansed_tbl_annt_txt,max(a.dw_etl_sess_nm),max(a.dw_ld_grp_val),max(a.dw_ins_dts),max(a.dw_upd_dts)
,b.db,b.schemaname,b.tablename,b.tabledescription,b.table_id,b.ts_updated,b.user_name
 from test.sample a INNER JOIN  test.sample1 b
 ON
 lower(a.schemaname)=lower(b.schemaname)
 AND lower(a.tablename)=lower(b.tablename)
 where a.schemaname is not null
 group by a.schemaname,a.tablename
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to aggregate functions_.

Comment: Try to GROUP BY/aggregate in a subqeury - before joining b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate first, join later:

```sql
SELECT a.*
     , b.db, b.schemaname, b.tablename, b.tabledescription, b.table_id, b.ts_updated, b.user_name
FROM  (
   SELECT schemaname, tablename
        , max(tbl_cmmt_txt) AS tbl_cmmt_txt, max(cleansed_tbl_cmmt_txt) AS cleansed_tbl_cmmt_txt, ...  -- more
   FROM   test.sample a
   WHERE  schemaname IS NOT NULL
   GROUP  BY schemaname, tablename
   ) a
JOIN   test.sample1 b ON lower(a.schemaname) = lower(b.schemaname)
                     AND lower(a.tablename) = lower(b.tablename);
```

See:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

I removed `DISTINCT` on a hunch. It's unclear if table `sample1` can hold duplicate matches and what you want to pick in this case.

You might want `LEFT JOIN` instead, depending on your undisclosed objective.

Also, `lower(tablename)` and `lower(schemaname)` are suspicious. Postgres identifiers are case-sensitive when double-quoted. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

And it reeks that you aggregate on `schemaname ...` but join on `lower(schemaname) ...`. Typically, you'd want the same for both.