# SQL: two aggregate functions without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

How to use two aggregate functions (for example double `string_agg` or just `sum`), but ensure that the results do not contain duplicates caused by the other aggregate function (caused by second join)? I use PostgreSQL.

### Example

I have three tables:

```
create table boxes
(
    id   bigserial primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);

create table animals
(
    id     bigserial primary key,
    name   varchar(255),
    age    numeric,
    box_id bigint constraint animals_boxes_id references boxes
);

create table vegetables
(
    id     bigserial primary key,
    name   varchar(255),
    weight numeric,
    box_id bigint constraint vegatables_box_id references boxes
);
```

Some input data:

```
insert into boxes (name) values ('First box');
insert into animals (box_id, name, age) values (1, 'Cat', 2);
insert into animals (box_id, name, age) values (1, 'Cat', 3);
insert into animals (box_id, name, age) values (1, 'Dog', 5);
insert into vegetables (box_id, name, weight) values (1, 'Tomato', 20);
insert into vegetables (box_id, name, weight) values (1, 'Cucumber', 30);
insert into vegetables (box_id, name, weight) values (1, 'Potato', 50);
```

And I want to get animal names in boxes:

```
select b.name                                 as box_name,
       string_agg(a.name, ', ' order by a.id) as animal_names
from boxes as b
         left join animals a on b.id = a.box_id
group by b.name;
```

It works:

| box_name | animal_names |
| --- | --- |
| First box | Cat, Cat, Dog |

But I also want to get vegetable names. But it **doesn't work**:

```
select b.name                                 as box_name,
       string_agg(a.name, ', ' order by a.id) as animal_names,
       string_agg(v.name, ', ' order by v.id) as vegatable_names
from boxes as b
         left join animals a on b.id = a.box_id
         left join vegetables v on b.id = v.box_id
group by b.name;
```

It produces duplicates in animal names and vegetable names:

| box_name | animal_names | vegatable_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First box | Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat, Dog, Dog, Dog | Tomato, Tomato, Tomato, Cucumber, Cucumber, Cucumber, Potato, Potato, Potato |

Result should be:

| box_name | animal_names | vegatable_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First box | Cat, Cat, Dog | Tomato, Cucumber, Potato |

I can't just add `distinct` to remove duplicates because:

- Names in tables can duplicates (two animals with name `Cat`). If I use `distinct` it produces `Cat, Dog` instead of `Cat, Cat, Dog`.
- I use `order by` in `string_agg` (it cause `ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list` when added `distinct`). Even if I remove `order by` (`string_agg(distinct a.name, ', ')`) I can't use it because first point.

#### Additional info

It applies to all aggregates function: `string_agg`, `array_agg`, `json_object_agg` and even `sum`.

Sum age of animals:

```
select sum(a.age)
from boxes as b
         left join animals a on b.id = a.box_id
         -- left join vegetables v on b.id = v.box_id
group by b.name;
```

Without second join it calculates correctly (`10`) but with it wrong (`30`) - due to duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is explained here:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

For a small selection, aggregation per row is typically faster.
With **`LATERAL` subqueries** (more versatile):

```sql
SELECT b.name AS box_name, a.*, v.*
FROM   boxes b
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(a.name, ', ' ORDER BY a.id) AS animal_names
   FROM   animals a
   WHERE  a.box_id = b.id
   ) a ON true
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(v.name, ', ' ORDER BY v.id) AS vegetable_names
   FROM   vegetables v
   WHERE  v.box_id = b.id
   ) v ON true;
```

Or with **correlated subqueries** (simpler, often a bit faster):

```sql
SELECT b.name AS box_name
    , (SELECT string_agg(a.name, ', ' ORDER BY a.id)
       FROM   animals a
       WHERE  a.box_id = b.id)  AS animal_names
    , (SELECT string_agg(v.name, ', ' ORDER BY v.id)
       FROM   vegetables v
       WHERE  v.box_id = b.id) AS vegetable_names
FROM   boxes b;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

While aggregating the whole table, this is faster:

```sql
SELECT b.name AS box_name, a.animal_names, v.vegetable_names
FROM   boxes b
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT box_id, string_agg(a.name, ', ') AS animal_names   
   FROM  (
      SELECT box_id, id, name
      FROM   animals a
      ORDER  BY box_id, id
      ) a
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a ON a.box_id = b.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT box_id, string_agg(v.name, ', ') AS vegetable_names 
   FROM  (
      SELECT box_id, id, name
      FROM   vegetables v
      ORDER  BY box_id, id
      ) v
   GROUP  BY 1   
   ) v ON v.box_id = b.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SeRs7pkE)

Note how I sort in a subquery, which is typically faster than doing a per-aggregate sort. An optional optimization.

Aside: about `varchar(255)` in your test setup:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21496/3684)

Answer (score -1):

try to join the `vegetables` table to the `animals` table

```
SELECT b.name AS box_name
    ,string_agg(a.name, ', ' ORDER BY a.id) AS animal_names
    ,string_agg(v.name, ', ' ORDER BY v.id) AS vegetable_names
FROM boxes AS b
LEFT JOIN animals a ON b.id = a.box_id
LEFT JOIN vegetables v ON v.id = a.id
GROUP BY b.name;
```

output:

| box_name | animal_names | vegetable_names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First box | Cat, Cat, Dog | Tomato, Cucumber, Potato |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QMhJtraG) here