# How to include columns from two tables based on a common column value but include rows only from the left table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-14

I have two tables **tb1** and **tb2**. **tb2** is connected to **tb1** via a foreign key named **tk_id**.  Here is how my two tables look like

**tb1**

```
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                      
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('tb2_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 modified_at     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 status          | double precision            |           | not null | 
 tk_id           | uuid                        |           | not null |
```

**tb2**

```
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id             | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 modified_at    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 destination_id | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 source_id      | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 tk_id          | uuid                        |           | not null |
```

Now I need to get all rows from **tb1** which has columns from both **tb1** and **tb2** when the **tk_id** value matches for both the rows.

This is what I tried:

```
select tb1.created_at, tb1.status, tb2.source_id, tb2.destination_id from tb1 
inner join tb2 on tb1.tk_id = tb2.tk_id where 
tb1.created_at > timezone('utc', now()) - interval '40 minutes';
```

But I am getting way too many rows. Usually in a **40min** interval, there would be around **800** records but after the join, I am getting around **100,000+** records.

**EDIT:** After some reading and a few tries, I made some changes in my query and managed to get the rows down to the expected number of rows. This is my query now

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tk_id FROM tb2) t2 
ON tb1.tk_id = t2.tk_id where tb1.created_at > timezone('utc', now()) - 
interval '40 minutes';
```

But now I can't get the columns of **tb2** in my select query.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT2:** Sorry if I couldn't make this clearer earlier. The join condition should be based on the latest occurrence of **tk_id** of the right table. So for every row of left table (**tb1**), it should match against the latest occurrence of **tk_id** of right table (**tb2**) and fetch the right table's columns.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: *Now I need to get all rows from tb1 which has columns from both tb1 and tb2 when the tk_id value matches for both the rows.* Not sure what you mean here;  sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: @GMB hi, what I mean is that rows should only belong to left table while also including columns from right table.

Comment: Sample data for each table and desired results of that data, all as text - **no images**. Further included current query and the results from that query - also as text. A [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are obviously many rows in `tb2` for a single row in `tb1`, you need to define **which** row to pick. Or some aggregation?

This query returns all qualifying rows from `tb1`, and adds columns from the *one* matching row in `tb2` that was created last (if any):

```sql
SELECT tb1.created_at, tb1.status, tb2.*
FROM   tb1
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT tb2.source_id, tb2.destination_id
   FROM   tb2
   WHERE  tb2.tk_id = tb1.tk_id
   ORDER  BY created_at DESC, id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) tb2 ON true
WHERE  tb1.created_at > timezone('utc', now()) - interval '40 minutes';
```

Added `id DESC` as tiebreaker since `created_at` might not be unique.
Adapt to your undisclosed needs.

Related:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [SQL: two aggregate functions without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514703/sql-two-aggregate-functions-without-duplicates/76514912#76514912)

Support this query with an index on `tb2(tk_id, created_at, id)`.
And another index on `tb1(created_at)`, obviously. Or even a covering index on `tb1(created_at) INCLUDE (tk_id, status)`. See:

- [Advantage of using INCLUDE as against adding the column in INDEX for covering index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313280/3684)
- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)