WHERE on INNER JOIN table but include all rows that match on right table
I have 2 tables with a 1-to-many relationship. Table A contains 'OBJECTS' and table B contains 'COMPONENTS' have id's that are related and I wrote a query to gather all OBJECTS from table A and associated COMPONENTS from table B that looks like this:
SELECT A.*, ARRAY_AGG(B.*)
FROM A INNER JOIN B USING(id)
GROUP BY A.*

This gives me what I expect.
Next I have a field on B called 'type' that can be 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'. I want to do the same query above, but filter the results such that only OBJECTS that have associated COMPONENTS where B.type = 'X'. Furthermore, I still want all associated COMPONENTS that aren't B.type = 'X' for each returned OBJECT.
My first attempt was to write the following query:
SELECT A.*, ARRAY_AGG(B.*)
FROM A INNER JOIN B USING(id)
WHERE B.type = 'X'
GROUP BY A.*

But this query strips COMPONENTS that aren't type = 'X'.
Is there a way to get all OBJECTS that have associated COMPONENTS with type = 'X' but also the result set returns all associated COMPONENTS for each object regardless of type?
Here's an example dataset with the expected result set:
A:



id




1


2


3


4



B:



id
type




1
X


1
Y


1
Z


2
Y


2
Z


3
X


4
Z



Result:
(1, [(1,X),(1,Y),(1,Z)]),
(3, [(3,X)])

These queries are part of an SQLX Rust project, if that makes a difference.

While referential integrity is enforced, and you query for all IDs, you don't even have to include table A in the query:
SELECT id, array_agg(B.*)
FROM   B
GROUP  BY id
HAVING bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE type = 'X');

About the aggregate FILTER clause:

Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters

Should be as fast as it gets - unless type = 'X' is rare.
In which case - assuming B(type, id) is unique:
SELECT id, array_agg(B.*)
FROM  (SELECT id FROM B WHERE type = 'X') b1
JOIN   B USING (id)
GROUP  BY 1;

With one index on (type, id) - could be the UNIQUE constraint with leading type.
(Better yet, a partial index on (id) WHERE type = 'X', but that may be too specialized.)
And another one on just (id), which should be a given.
If B(type, id) is not unique, add DISTINCT to the subquery or switch to IN or EXISTS, like:
SELECT id, array_agg(B.*)
FROM   B
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM B b1 WHERE b1.id = b.id AND b1.type = 'X')
GROUP  BY 1;


Is HAVING bool_or(true) FILTER (WHERE type = 'X') faster than the more idiomatic HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'X') > 0

Thanks for the input! The example is overly simple compared to my actual product. Table A contains more columns than just ID that I also need included in the solution so I dont think leaving A out of the query will be sufficient. The 'types' in table B arent rare, there's like a dozen of them distributed relatively equally over many 100's of 1000's of rows. I'll test out using the HAVING clause see how it works out. Sorry the simple example led you to specific optimizations I didnt need but maybe it'll be helpful to others who find this.

@Charlieface: Doesn't make much of a difference. bool_or is ever so slightly faster.

@GhostCrab: I see. Then join to A after all. But best after aggregating, should be faster. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626358/939860

@erwin-brandstetter Ok one more wrinkle - Table A stores time-series data. Nearly all queries on the database define a time span WHERE clause for Table A, dramatically reducing the result set. I think that would lead to it being more performant to aggregate B after filtering on time (and any other columns in A).

@GhostCrab: Exactly. Hence my bold disclaimer in the linked answer: "if you retrieve all or most of the rows in the base tables". Your case might even be a candidate for a correlated or LATERAL subquery. (Examples in the same referenced answer.) Seems like you over-simplified the question ...

@erwin-brandstetter Apologies. I didnt realize the magnitude the mitigating factors would have on the solution of my original question. I tried to keep it simple to make my question clearly stated.

@GhostCrab, Hi, and welcome to dba.se! “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler” - attributed to Einstein, but see here. In future, if possible, could you include a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your question - and make the example an MVCE - a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example - see my profile here for tips on how to ask questions - dba.se, but would apply to your question also. Also, include any indexs, PK's and FK's.

@GhostCrab Cardinalities would also be helpful!

It sounds like you're looking for a HAVING clause.
SELECT A.*
     , ARRAY_AGG(B.*)F
FROM A JOIN B USING(id) 
GROUP BY A.*
HAVING 'X'=ANY(ARRAY_AGG(B.type));
--HAVING bool_or(B.type='X');

Here's doc on bool_or() and other aggregates, here's on ANY array comparisons.
