# I have different results from query for COUNT('e.id') or COUNT(e.id)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, count, left-join

I have following code:

```
def self.department_members(department)
  where(organization_id: department.organization_id)
    .joins("LEFT JOIN core_employments As e ON
      e.organization_id = #{department.organization_id} AND
      core_members.user_id = e.user_id")
    .group('core_members.id')
end

def self.can_automerged(department)
  department_members(department).having("COUNT('e.id') = 1")
  # department_members(department).having("COUNT(e.id) = 1")
end

def self.can_not_automerged(department)
  department_members(department).having("Count('e.id') > 1")
end
```

When I use

```
department_members(department).having("COUNT('e.id') = 1")
```

my test completes without errors. When I use

```
department_members(department).having("COUNT(e.id) = 1")
```

my test fails. I can't understand why. Can u explain why?
I use Rails-4 and PostgreSQL.

schema:

```
  create_table "core_members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                                    null: false
    t.integer  "project_id",                                 null: false
    t.boolean  "owner",                      default: false
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "project_access_state"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.integer  "organization_department_id"
  end

  create_table "core_employments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.boolean  "primary"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "organization_department_id"
  end
```

test:

```
module Core
  require "initial_create_helper"
  describe Member do
    describe "automerge" do
      before(:each) do
        @organization = create(:organization)
        @department1 = create(:organization_department,organization: @organization)
        @department2 = create(:organization_department,organization: @organization)

        @user = create(:user)
        @user_with_many_employments = create(:user)

        @department1.employments.create!(user: @user)
        @department1.employments.create!(organization: @organization, user: @user_with_many_employments)
        @department2.employments.create!(organization: @organization, user: @user_with_many_employments)
        @project = create_project
        @project.members.create!(user: @user,
                                organization: @organization)
        @project.members.create!(user: @user_with_many_employments,
                                organization: @organization)

      end

      it "::can_not_automerged" do
        expect(Member.can_not_automerged(@department1).to_a.map(&:user)).to match_array [@user_with_many_employments]
      end
      it "::can_automerged" do
        expect(Member.can_automerged(@department1).to_a.map(&:user)).to match_array [@user]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I decided to count members without departments too with "coalesce" built-in function.   Anyway your answer is complete and correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have different results from query for COUNT('e.id') or COUNT(e.id)

`'e.id'` is a string constant, so `COUNT('e.id')` is just an awkward, misleading  way of saying `COUNT(*)`.

`COUNT(e.id)`, on the other hand, counts all rows in the result where `e.id IS NOT NULL` - since `count()` does not count NULL values.

[The manual about `count()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

> `count(*)` ... number of input rows
>
> `count(expression)` ... number of input rows for which
>   the value of expression is not null

As you can see, there are even two separate functions internally. And 
it should be noted that `count(*)` is slightly faster. So use that unless you *need* the second variant. Related:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

You might counter with:
*"But `e.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `core_employments`, so it is defined `NOT NULL`!"*

But that would overlook the **conditional `LEFT JOIN`** in your query that still introduces `NULL` values in your `NOT NULL` column, where the join conditions are not met. Related:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

That said, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` is misleading, too. The later condition

```
having("COUNT(e.id) = 1")
```

forces it to act like a plain `[INNER] JOIN`. Once you have fixed that, you might as well simplify to:

```
having("COUNT(*) = 1")
```

And if all you care is that ***at least*** one related row exists in `core_employments`, translating to `having("COUNT(*) >= 1")`, the superior (clearer, faster) technique in simple cases would be an [`EXISTS` semi-join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM core_employments WHERE <conditions>)
```