# Difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_DATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I want to get the data from the last 28 days and only include complete days. So what I mean is, when I look at the data today at 10:00 AM, it only includes data from yesterday (the completed day) and 28 days before yesterday.

I am creating a live dashboard with figures like this. So I don't want the numbers to change until the day is finished.

Also, I am willing to understand the difference between `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

For example, in my code, if I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, will I get the data from today 10:00 AM back to 28 days ago 10:00 AM? if not, how can I get data in a way numbers change live according to every time I run the code (the average time that data change in the database is 10 minutes).

My simplified code:

```
select count(id) from customers 
where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - interval '28 days'
```

Maybe I am using wrong code, can you please give me advice on how to get the date in both formats:

1. include only complete days(does not include today, until the day is
   finished)
2. include hours, from today morning until 28 days back same
   time in the morning.

Comment: why not use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '28 days'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `created_at` is of type `timestamptz`.

> 1. include only complete days(does not include today, until the day is
>          finished)

Start with `now()` and use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   customers 
WHERE  created_at <  date_trunc('day', now())
AND    created_at >= date_trunc('day', now() - interval '28 days');
```

Or work with `CURRENT_DATE` ...

```
WHERE  created_at <  CURRENT_DATE
AND    created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - 28;
```

The result for both depends on the current `timezone` setting. The "date" functionally depends on your current time zone. The type `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) does not. But the expression `date_trunc('day', now())` introduces the same dependency as the "day" is defined by your current time zone. So you need to define which "days" you mean precisely. Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

You can subtract `integer` values from a `date` to subtract days:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)

`now()` is a shorter equivalent of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

`count(*)` is equivalent to `count(id)` while `id` is defined  `NOT NULL`, but a bit faster.

- [I have different results from query for COUNT('e.id') or COUNT(e.id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086813/i-have-different-results-from-query-for-counte-id-or-counte-id/50087600#50087600)

> 2. include hours, from today morning until 28 days back same time in the morning.

Simply:

```
WHERE  created_at > now() - interval '28 days'
```

No dependency on the current time zone.