# Сombining date columns into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

The database has columns with the date of conclusion of the contract and the date of termination of the contract. I need to group by date the number of conclusions and the number of cancellations.

I have written queries

```
with conn as (select date_signing::date as dt_sign, count(date_signing) as signing from services GROUP by date_signing::date),
disconn as (select date_cancellation::date as dt_canc, count(date_cancellation) as cancelling from services GROUP by date_cancellation::date)
select * from conn full join disconn on conn.dt_sign = disconn.dt_canc
```

Here is the result:

[image]

But I need this result (for example):

```
date        signing       cancelling
2019-08-09     1             null
2020-05-05   null              1
```

I need one column with date and columns with signing and termination to see the dynamics.
Please tell me in which direction to think.

Comment: The output in your image does not seem to make sense. Also, please show data as text to begin with, never as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULL JOIN` looks ok for the job. Minor suggestions:

```sql
WITH sig AS (
   SELECT date_signing::date AS the_date, count(*) AS signing
   FROM   services
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
, can AS (
   SELECT date_cancellation::date AS the_date, count(*) AS cancelling
   FROM   services
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT *
FROM   sig
FULL   JOIN can USING (the_date)
WHERE  the_date IS NOT NULL;  -- optional to eliminate row(s) with null date
```

To simplify, use the same column alias and join with the `USING` clause to get a single output column.

Also, `count(*)` is faster and equivalent for this (except for also getting the correct count for `the_date IS NULL`).

Related:

- [I have different results from query for COUNT('e.id') or COUNT(e.id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086813/i-have-different-results-from-query-for-counte-id-or-counte-id/50087600#50087600)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i need! Now I understand how to combine columns!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want gaps in this report, and especially if you want to zoom in on a period, generate a calendar and `left join` to it. Counts on that also yield a proper zero instead of `null`. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMTYhXmE):

```sql
select d::date,count(*)filter(where d::date=s.date_signing::date)signing,
               count(*)filter(where d::date=s.date_cancellation::date)cancelling 
from generate_series('2023-02-22'::timestamp,'2023-03-11','1 day')_(d)
left join services s on d::date in(s.date_signing::date,s.date_cancellation::date)
group by 1 order by 1;
```

If you like your current layout, you don't need to `join` at all. Read out the dates and `sum()`:

```sql
select the_date, sum(s)signing, sum(c)cancelling
from (select  date_cancellation::date AS the_date,0 AS s,1 AS c from services
      union all select date_signing::date,1,0 from services)_
group by 1 order by 1;
```

or with similar pre/sub-aggregation:

```sql
select the_date, sum(s)signing, sum(c)cancelling from (
  select date_cancellation::date the_date,0 s,count(*)c from services group by 1
  union all select date_signing::date,count(*),0 from services group by 1)_
group by 1 order by 1;
```

[Performance&plans](https://dbfiddle.uk/yJK-weLk)

---

`unnest()` into an aggragate:

```sql
select the_date,sum(s)signing,sum(c)cancelling 
from services, 
unnest(array[ (date_cancellation::date, 0    ,1    )
             ,(date_signing::date     , 1    ,0    ) ] )
             _(the_date date          , s int,c int)
group by 1 order by 1;
```

```
select the_date,sum(s::int)signing,sum((not s)::int)cancelling 
from services,
unnest(array[true,false],
       array[date_signing,date_cancellation]::date[])_(s,the_date)
group by 1 order by 1;
```

```
select the_date,count(*)filter(where o='signing'   )signing
               ,count(*)filter(where o='cancelling')cancelling
from services,
unnest(array['signing'   ,'cancelling'],
       array[date_signing,date_cancellation]::date[])_(o,the_date)
group by 1 order by 1;
```

```
select the_date::date
      ,sum( extract(h from the_date))signing
      ,sum((extract(h from the_date) =0)::int)cancelling 
from services,
unnest(array[date_signing::date+interval'1h',date_cancellation::date])_(the_date)
group by 1 order by 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! You have given me a lot of new knowledge!