# Generalizing a CASE statement (with dynamic names for result columns?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate, dynamic-sql

I currently have a query like so -

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'January' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan", 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb", 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'March' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Mar", 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'April' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "April", 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'May' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "May", 
   SUM(CASE month WHEN 'June' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "June"   
FROM tbl
WHERE start >= '2021-01-01'
AND   start <= '2021-06-30'
```

This query needs to run for the last 6 months every month. For example, since the current month has not ended yet, this query needs to run from Jan 1 to June 30. How do I automate this query so I don't have to change the `CASE` statements or the dates in the `WHERE` clause every month.

**The output I am expecting**

```
Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  June
2    2    3    6    1    4
```

Comment: I think it may be useful to use the GETDATE () function
 and then you subtract 1 month that way every time it arrives
 next month you will always have your 6 months

Comment: you can declare some variables for that and run through an SP

Comment: Why are you storing the month in a separate column if you also have a date column?

Comment: "Jan", "Feb", ... but "April"? Not "Apr"?

Comment: It can be `Apr` or `April` as long as I can run it every month without having to change a bunch of things. @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `month` seems to be redundant. Drop it from the table. `start` has all the information you need.
(I'd rather not use `start` as column name as that's a [keyword in standard SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) - even if allowed in Postgres.)

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', start) AS mon, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
WHERE  start >= '2021-01-01'
AND    start <  '2021-07-01'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Use `date_trunc()` to preserve chronological order. If you need month names in the result:

```sql
WITH cte(current_mon) AS (SELECT date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP))
SELECT to_char(mon, 'Mon') AS month, COALESCE(data.ct, 0) AS ct
FROM   cte c
CROSS  JOIN generate_series(c.current_mon - interval '6 mon'
                          , c.current_mon - interval '1 mon' 
                          , interval '1 mon') mon
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', start) AS mon, count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   tbl, cte c
   WHERE  start >= c.current_mon - interval '6 mon'
   AND    start <  c.current_mon
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) data USING (mon)
ORDER  BY mon;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e3b09fd0430bf2204787382b75bdceb)*

Returns one row per month, in chronological order (considering the year, too, though it's not in your output!), and truly dynamic.

| month | ct |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 31 |
| Feb | 28 |
| Mar | 31 |
| Apr | 0 |
| May | 31 |
| Jun | 30 |

Note how I first build timestamps for the last six months (excluding the current one) with `generate_series()` in the first subquery `mon`. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Then `LEFT JOIN` to counts per month from the relevant time range. This way always returns the last 6 months, even if no rows are found at all. `COALESCE` makes the count 0 instead of NULL for that case. Related:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Note, in particular, that it's faster to aggregate first and join later. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Using standard English month names and 3-letter-abbreviations.

Your original query produces that information in pivoted form: one month per column. **But dynamic column names are not possible for a static SQL query.** If you really need that, you need a 2-step flow of operation (two round trips to the server):

1. Build the query.
2. Execute it.

Well, you ***could*** prepare 12 different row types (that's the range of possible result types for your case) and use a polymorphic function to achieve it. But do you actually *need* the pivoted form?

### OK, you asked for it ...

You want a simple call like this?

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_counts_6months(NULL::m6_jul);
```

It's possible. Here is a proof of concept.
*But, honestly, I'd rather avoid the complication and just use the simple query above.*

Create a polymorphic function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_counts_6months(ANYELEMENT)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYELEMENT 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _current_mon timestamp := date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP);
BEGIN
   -- to prevent incorrect column names, input row type must match current date:
   IF right(pg_typeof($1)::text, 3) = to_char(_current_mon, 'mon') THEN
      -- all good!
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Current date is %. Function requires input >>%<<'
                    , CURRENT_DATE, 'NULL::m6_' || to_char(now(), 'mon');
   END IF;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT a[2], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]
   FROM (
      SELECT ARRAY(
         SELECT COALESCE(data.ct, 0)
         FROM   generate_series(_current_mon - interval '6 mon'
                              , _current_mon - interval '1 mon'
                              , interval '1 mon') mon
         LEFT   JOIN (
            SELECT date_trunc('month', start) AS mon, count(*)::int AS ct
            FROM   tbl
            GROUP  BY 1
            ) data USING (mon)
         ORDER  BY mon
         )
      ) sub(a);
END
$func$;
```

And 12 composite (row) types, one for each month of the year:

```sql
CREATE TYPE m6_jan AS ("Jul" int, "Aug" int, "Sep" int, "Oct" int, "Nov" int, "Dec" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_feb AS ("Aug" int, "Sep" int, "Oct" int, "Nov" int, "Dec" int, "Jan" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_mar AS ("Sep" int, "Oct" int, "Nov" int, "Dec" int, "Jan" int, "Feb" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_apr AS ("Oct" int, "Nov" int, "Dec" int, "Jan" int, "Feb" int, "Mar" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_may AS ("Nov" int, "Dec" int, "Jan" int, "Feb" int, "Mar" int, "Apr" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_jun AS ("Dec" int, "Jan" int, "Feb" int, "Mar" int, "Apr" int, "May" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_jul AS ("Jan" int, "Feb" int, "Mar" int, "Apr" int, "May" int, "Jun" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_aug AS ("Feb" int, "Mar" int, "Apr" int, "May" int, "Jun" int, "Jul" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_sep AS ("Mar" int, "Apr" int, "May" int, "Jun" int, "Jul" int, "Aug" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_oct AS ("Apr" int, "May" int, "Jun" int, "Jul" int, "Aug" int, "Sep" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_nov AS ("May" int, "Jun" int, "Jul" int, "Aug" int, "Sep" int, "Oct" int);
CREATE TYPE m6_dec AS ("Jun" int, "Jul" int, "Aug" int, "Sep" int, "Oct" int, "Nov" int);
```

Then the simple function call works and returns exactly your desired result:

```sql
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_counts_6months(NULL::m6_jul);
```

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | 28 | 31 | 0 | 31 | 30 |

Why? How? See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

You are required to call with the right type. I built in a fail-safe to prevent wrong results. If you call with the wrong type, like the following call in July (currently):

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_counts_6months(NULL::m6_nov);
```

... the function throws an exception with instructions:

```
ERROR:  Current date is 2021-07-15. Function requires input >>NULL::m6_jul<<
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f_tbl_counts_6months(anyelement) line 9 at RAISE
```

Comment: This does not align with the output I am expecting. I have updated the question with the updated output.

Comment: Yes, I need the pivoted form for a report.

Comment: I can't add 12 different CASE statements because then the report will have 12 columns. I only need columns for the last 6 months.

Comment: @Aaron: The core question is: do you need dynamic column names? That's the tricky part. (And typically not what you want in client code anyway!) The rest is not that hard.

Comment: I do need dynamic column names. If that is not an option, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Go back `1` month from the date now : the result is the end date : `DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())`

`7` months back to be the start date : `DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETDATE())`

To calculate the first day of the month, subtract today from itself : `(DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)`

**get end date**

```
    sql => select DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - (DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)
    postgresql => SELECT now() - INTERVAL '1 month' - (extract(day from now()) - 1 || ' day')::INTERVAL;
```

---

**get start date**

```
    sql => select DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETDATE()) - (DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)
    postgresql => select now() - INTERVAL '7 month' - (extract(day from now()) - 1 || ' day')::INTERVAL;
```

---

**query**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'January' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan", 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb", 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'March' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Mar", 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'April' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "April", 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'May' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "May", 
  SUM(CASE month WHEN 'June' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "June"   
FROM dateTable
WHERE start >= now() - INTERVAL '7 month' - (extract(day from now()) - 1 || ' day')::INTERVAL
AND start <= now() - INTERVAL '1 month' - (extract(day from now()) - 1 || ' day')::INTERVAL;
```

postgresql demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=85c2d024f087a0b7150e5ca59c68eb66)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS DATE = DATEADD(d, -31, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, GETDATE()) - 6, 0))
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS DATE = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1,  GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 

SELECT 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'January' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan", 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb", 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'March' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Mar", 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'April' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "April", 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'May' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "May", 
SUM(CASE month WHEN 'June' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "June"   
WHERE start >= @STARTDATE
AND start <= @ENDDATE
```

Comment: I am on Postgres.