# How to get columns which are not in GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a Postgresql database where I have these two tables.

`shipping_method`

```
id | name     | abbrev
---+----------+-------
1  | Standard | ST
2  | Express  | EX
```

`shipping_details`:

| id | shipping_method_id | estimated_time_min | estimated_time_max | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 02:00:00 | 04:00:00 | 230 |
| 3 | 2 | 00:03:00 | 01:00:00 | 500 |
| 4 | 1 | 02:00:00 | 04:00:00 | 1230 |
| 5 | 1 | 02:00:00 | 04:00:00 | 850 |
| 6 | 2 | 01:00:00 | 02:00:00 | 1785 |

My goal is to fetch the most expensive shipping details per shipping method (for a specific product [not in OP]).

So far, I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
    sm.id, sm.name, MAX(sd.price) AS max_price
FROM 
    shipping_details AS sd 
LEFT JOIN 
    shipping_method AS sm ON sm.id = sd.shipping_method_id
GROUP BY 
    sm.id
```

which returns:

```
id | name     | max_price
---+----------+---------
2  | Express  | 1785
1  | Standard | 1230
```

Through that query, I am not able to get the `shipping_details` columns without putting them in `GROUP BY` clause. I mainly need shipping details for each specific shipping method that has the higher price.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sm.id) sm.id, sm.name, sd.price AS max_price
FROM shipping_details AS sd 
LEFT JOIN shipping_method AS sm
    ON sm.id = sd.shipping_method_id
ORDER BY sm.id, sd.price DESC;
```

The above logic will return the shipping method having the max price.

Comment: It works ;-). However, can you explain why you have this `(sm.id) sm.id`. Why you have it twice?

Comment: @Lemayzeur The `(sm.id)` term tells Postgres that you want to find the max record per group of records belonging to the same shipping method.  The `ORDER BY` clause tells Postgres to find the one record per group having the max price.

Comment: Perfect. This solution works well and it takes less time to execute

Answer (score 1):

To get additional columns from each row with the highest price in `shipping_details`, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT sm.id, sm.name, sd.*
FROM   shipping_method sm
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (shipping_method_id)
          shipping_method_id AS id, price AS max_price
      --  add more columns as you like
   FROM   shipping_details sd
   ORDER  BY sd.shipping_method_id DESC, sd.price DESC, sd.id  -- ①
   ) sd USING (id);
```

As long as all rows from `shipping_details` are involved, it's typically fastest to aggregate first, and *then* join. (Not when the table holds many additional rows that are eliminated by the join.)

If `price` can be `NULL` make that `ORDER  BY ... price DESC NULLS LAST` - else `NULL` sorts on top in descending order. Be sure to match an existing index.

① An index on `shipping_details (shipping_method_id, prize)` makes it fast if the table `shipping_details` is big. Or an index on `(shipping_method_id DESC, prize DESC)`. It's important that the **sort order of both columns are in sync with the query**. Postgres can scan the index forwards or backwards, but for multicolumn indices the sort order of all columns needs to be in sync with the query. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)

One more issue to note: If there can be multiple shipping details with the highest price, you get an arbitrary pick which can change with every execution, typically after writes to involved rows. To get a stable, deterministic result, add more `ORDER BY` expressions as tiebreaker. Like `sd.id` I appended above. Then the smallest `id` is the winner, consistently.
If there are *many* ties like that, it even pays to append `id` to the index. Like `(shipping_method_id, prize, id DESC)` - note the opposite sort order for `id`!

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

There may be (much) faster techniques, depending on undisclosed details. Assuming ***many*** rows per shipping method, and an applicable index as discussed, this should be ***much*** faster:

```sql
SELECT sm.id, sm.name, sd.*
FROM   shipping_method sm
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sd.price AS max_price, id AS shipping_details_id
   FROM   shipping_details sd
   WHERE  sd.shipping_method_id = sm.id
   ORDER  BY sd.price DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) sd ON true;
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/34715134#34715134) (note performance of query nr. 5!)

Comment: Yes, It works. I appreciate your answer. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408600/5644965) takes less time to execute. Thank you!

Comment: That's unexpected. This one should be a bit faster - unless there are additional rows in `shipping_details` that are not needed for the query (`shipping_method_id` can be NULL or no FK constraint). Maybe `NULLS LAST` makes a difference. Can be removed if `price` is `NOT NULL`. As long as you match an existing index.

Comment: I only have added `id as shipping_details_id` where you put the comment. The execution time becomes a bit closer with your recent edit

Comment: @Lemayzeur: I think I pinned down the performance issue. Consider the update.

Comment: Can you help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70188086/what-makes-that-postgresql-query-slow)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is one way using window function:

```
select *
from shipping_method sm 
join (
      select *, row_number() over (partition by shipping_method_id order by price desc) rn  
      from shipping_details sd) t 
on sd.shipping_method_id = t.id
and rn = 1 ;
```

Comment: This is the same result as what I have done in OP. How do I get the `shipping_details` related to it?

Comment: @Lemayzeur , oh I missed the point . see my updated answer