# What makes that postgreSQL query slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have this query, where it seems to me with too much JOIN.

The goal is to retrieve all locations with their most expensive (highest price) shipping details for a specific product. Note that we may have two different types of shipping: *Express* and *Standard*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT on(l.id, sm.id) l.id as location_id, sm.id as shipping_method_id,
    sm.name as shipping_method_name, sd.price
FROM location AS l

JOIN product_location_shipping AS pl_s 
    ON l.id = pl_s.location_id 
    
JOIN product_location_shipping_details AS pl_sd
    ON pl_s.id = pl_sd.product_location_shipping_id

JOIN shipping_details AS sd
    ON sd.id = pl_sd.shipping_details_id

JOIN shipping_method AS sm
    ON sm.id = sd.shipping_method_id
WHERE pl_s.product_id = 1
ORDER BY l.id, sm.id, sd.price DESC;
```

And the result is:

| location_id | shipping_method_id | shipping_method_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Standard | 230 |
| 1 | 2 | Express | 500 |
| 6 | 1 | Standard | 3900 |
| 6 | 2 | Express | 5230 |

Here is the structure of the tables. (Each column represents one table)

| location | shipping_method | shipping_details | product_location_shipping | product_location_shipping_details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id | id |
| name | name | price | location_id | product_location_shipping_id |
| zip_code | ... | estimated_time | product_id | shipping_details_id |
| .. | ... | shipping_method_id | ... | ... |

Is there any other ways to achieve this faster? or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Without the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide proper information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `DISTINCT ON()` part here. I'm guessing you have multiple prices per combination for some `l.id` and `sm.id` combinations and try to get rid of those? I'm also not sure if the `ORDER BY sd.price` will always give you the highest value in this construction.. (maybe it does? I find it weird). IMHO a `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` would be a lot more readable if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: I wanted to avoid too much joins, that was the purpose. I end up doing it in another way. So I am going to delete that question!

Answer (score 0):

You must have a minimum of the following indexes:

`id` fields of all tables must be PRIMARY KEY. For Example:

```
ALTER TABLE location ADD CONSTRAINT location_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE product_location_shipping  ADD CONSTRAINT product_location_shipping_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE product_location_shipping_details  ADD CONSTRAINT product_location_shipping_details_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE shipping_details  ADD CONSTRAINT shipping_details_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE shipping_method   ADD CONSTRAINT shipping_method_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Fields that are used on the `join` conditions and after the `order by` command must be an index of `btree` type. For Example:

```
CREATE INDEX product_location_shipping_location_id_idx 
ON product_location_shipping (location_id);

CREATE INDEX product_location_shipping_details_product_location_shipping_id_idx 
ON product_location_shipping_details (product_location_shipping_id);

CREATE INDEX shipping_details_shipping_details_id_idx 
ON shipping_details (shipping_details_id);

CREATE INDEX shipping_method_shipping_method_id_idx 
ON shipping_method (shipping_method_id);

CREATE INDEX shipping_details_price_idx 
ON shipping_details (price);
```