# Get the sum of (count(column1) + count(column2))

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, left-join

I have a table A:

```
entity_id    name
------------------
1            Test1
2            Test2
3            Test3
4            Test4
5            Test5
6            Test6
```

I have a table B:

```
entity_id   value1     value2
-----------------------------
1           10          20
1           15          30
2           10          25
1           9           45
3           null        1
2           45          50
3           20          null
```

I need to write a single query to select the entity_id and name from Table A and count the total occurrences for an entity_id of columns value1 and value2 from Table B and then the total of those column counts (null doesn't count).

So my output table would be:

```
entity_id    name         value1_count    value2_count     total_count
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Test1             3               3              6
2            Test2             1               2              3
3            Test3             1               1              2
4            Test4             0               0              0
5            Test5             0               0              0
6            Test6             0               0              0
```

I am having trouble summing the count of value1 and count of value2 and outputting that value in the total_count per unique entity_it.

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.entity_id, a.name
     , count(b.value1) AS value1_count, count(b.value2) AS value2_count, sum(2) AS total_count
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
GROUP BY a.entity_id, a.name
```

I know that the `sum(2) as total_count` is incorrect and doesn't get me what I want.

Comment: `value1_count` for entity 2 should be *2*, not *1* I assume?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT entity_id, a.name
     , COALESCE(b.v1_ct, 0) AS value1_count
     , COALESCE(b.v2_ct, 0) AS value2_count
     , COALESCE(b.v1_ct + b.v2_ct, 0) AS total_count
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT entity_id, count(value1) AS v1_ct, count(value2) AS v2_ct
   FROM   b
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (entity_id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a2f936920e804b8bbcc78612acb74a3)*

Aggregate first, join later. That's simpler and faster. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

`count()` never produces `NULL`. Only the `LEFT JOIN` can introduce `NULL` values for counts in this query, so `v1_ct` and `v2_ct` are either both `NULL` or both `NOT NULL`. Hence `COALESCE(v1_ct + v2_ct, 0)` is ok. (Else, one NULL would nullify the other summand in the addition.)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT b.entity_id
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE b.value1 IS NOT NULL) OVER () AS value1_count
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE b.value2 IS NOT NULL) OVER () AS value2_count
FROM Table_B AS b
GROUP BY b.entity_id
)
SELECT a.entity_id, a.name
     , COALESCE(l.value1_count, 0)
     , COALESCE(l.value2_count,0)
     , COALESCE(l.value1_count + l.value2_count, 0) AS total_count
FROM Table_A AS a
LEFT JOIN list AS l
ON a.entity_id = l.entity_id
```