# How can I improve this query without HAVING Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

There's two tables:

1. users
2. documents

`users`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

`documents`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id    INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    name       TEXT NOT NULL,
    value      INT NOT NULL 
)
```

I want to filter `users` by document `name` and `value`. Usually, between 2-5 document `name` and `value` is filtered. And there are apprx 6-10 documents per user.

I have a huge database and want to improve this query. I think I can get faster query without the `HAVING` clause. Any help highly appreciated. I use PostgreSQL 13.

The query I am using:

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('name', documents.name, 'value', documents.value))) AS docs
FROM
    users
JOIN
    documents
ON
    users.id = documents.user_id
GROUP BY
    users.username
HAVING
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', documents.name, 'value', documents.value)) @? '$[*] ? (@.name == "doc1") ? (@.value == "2")'
```

Comment: I edited to make the query consistent. Please fix if I got it wrong.

Comment: Please remember, actual `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints >>> freehand description.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it is right. And I changed description of tables to `SQL` Create statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For big tables it's **extremely expensive** to join and aggregate *all* rows before finally filtering the few qualifying rows.

It should be faster by orders of magnitude to filter qualifying documents first, then grab all documents for the same user(s), aggregate, and finally join to users:

```sql
SELECT u.username, d.docs
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', d.name, 'value', d.value)) AS docs
   FROM   documents d1
   JOIN   documents d USING (user_id)
   WHERE  d1.name = 'doc1'
   AND    d1.value = 2
   -- AND    d.name  IS NOT NULL  -- strip NULLs early 
   -- AND    d.value IS NOT NULL  -- if not defined NOT NULL anyway
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) d
JOIN   users u ON u.id = d.user_id;
```

While being at it, I removed `jsonb_strip_nulls()` since all processed columns are defined NOT NULL anyway. Also cheaper.

Possibly simplify to just `jsonb_build_object(d.name, d.value)`.

For the first step, an **index** on `documents(name, value)` will help ***a lot***. Maybe even on `documents(name, value, user_id)` to get [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) (depends).

It should be safe to assume there is also an index on `documents(user_id)`. Helps the next step. Again, `documents(user_id, name, value)` for index-only scans.

And, finally, an index on `users(id)`. Should be a given. Again, `users(id, username)` for index-only scans.

If `(name, value)` is not `UNIQUE` per user (like it seems to be the case), use `EXISTS` instead to avoid duplicates:

```sql
SELECT u.username, d.docs
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', d.name, 'value', d.value)) AS docs
   FROM   documents d
   WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM documents d1
      WHERE  d1.user_id = d.user_id
      AND    d1.name = 'doc1'
      AND    d1.value = 2
      )
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) d
JOIN   users u ON u.id = d.user_id;
```

Similar query plan, same indexes can be used.

Related:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Comment: That's better! But I get duplicate objects when I don't make any filtering. I tried to solve this but didn't succeed. Do you know a way to do it? I will use it in backend of a website where filtering is dynamically added.

Comment: And also, it is interesting, why does it generate same objects multiple times when filters are not added?

Comment: @Ulvi: The first query generate duplicates if `(name, value)` is not unique per user. I added an alternative to avoid duplicates, and some more to adjust to your updated table definition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hi Erwin, allow me. I didn't get the second query, not sure why do self join.  I think self join is unnecessary in this context..

Comment: @jian The semi-join with `EXISTS` in the 2nd query is necessary.