# WHERE clause does not find column after a CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, where-clause, common-table-expression

New to CTE's and subqueries in SQL.
I have 3 tables:

```
categories (category_code, category)
countries (country_code, country, continent)
businesses (business, year_founded, category_code, country_code)
```

Goal is to look at oldest businesses in the world. I used a CTE:

```sql
WITH bus_cat_cont AS (
    SELECT business, year_founded, category, country,   
           continent
    FROM businesses AS b
    INNER JOIN categories AS c1
    ON b.category_code = c1.category_code
    INNER JOIN countries AS c2
    ON b.country_code = c2.country_code
    )
SELECT continent,
       category,
       COUNT(business) AS n
FROM bus_cat_cont
WHERE n > 5
GROUP BY continent, category
ORDER BY n DESC;
```

The code works without `WHERE n > 5`. But after adding that, I get the error:

```
column "n" does not exist
```

I realized there is a much easier way to get the output I want without a CTE.
But I'm wondering: **Why do I get this error?**

Comment: That's correct : there is no `n` in the resulting set. (the `n` is a derived column in your outer query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```sql
WITH bus_cat_cont AS (
   SELECT business, year_founded, category, country, continent
   FROM   businesses AS b
   JOIN   categories AS c1 ON b.category_code = c1.category_code
   JOIN   countries  AS c2 ON b.country_code = c2.country_code
   )
SELECT continent, category, count(business) AS n
FROM   bus_cat_cont
-- WHERE  n > 5                -- wrong
GROUP  BY continent, category
HAVING count(business) > 5     -- right
ORDER  BY n DESC;
```

The *output* column name "n" is not visible (yet) in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause. Consider the sequence of events in an SQL query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

For the record, the result has no obvious connection to your declared goal to *"look at oldest businesses in the world"*. `year_founded` is unused in the query.
You get the most common continent/category combinations among businesses.

Aside, probably better:

```sql
SELECT co.continent, ca.category, n
FROM  (
   SELECT category_code, country_code, count(*) AS n
   FROM   businesses
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   HAVING count(*) > 5
   ) b
JOIN   categories ca USING (category_code)
JOIN   countries  co USING (country_code)
ORDER  BY n DESC;
```

There is really no need for a CTE.

Aggregate first, join later. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Beside being **faster**, this is also **safer**. While `category_code`, `country_code` should be defined `UNIQUE`, the same may not be true for `continent` and `category`. (You may want to output codes additionally to disambiguate.)

[`count(*)` is implemented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) separately and slightly faster - and equivalent while `business` is defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: This was so incredibly helpful. Thank you. I do realize that this code is not connected to my goal and it was irrelevant information to include on my part. It was only one step in a sample project I was working on on DataCamp. Thank you for the clarification!