# How to separate column values by condition (pivot) to fill one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate

I have two tables that I'd like do a `full outer join` where the resulting view separates the values table into two separate columns with one row for each `name_id`. I have made one approach with a `CASE` expression to select by type and then use it with pandas to fill in the values and return distinct name_ids.

Name Table

| name_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |
| 3 | doo |
| 4 | sue |

Values Table

| name_id | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | red |
| 2 | 95 | blue |
| 3 | 33 | red |
| 3 | 35 | blue |
| 4 | 60 | blue |
| 4 | 20 | red |

This is a condensed version. In my full table, I need to do this twice with two separate value tables sorted by type, red/blue and control/placebo.

Simple Join

```
SELECT names_table.name_id, name, value, type
FULL OUTER JOIN values_table
ON names_table.name_id = values_table.name_id
WHERE type in ('red', 'blue')
```

| name_id | name | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 90 | red |
| 2 | bar | 95 | blue |
| 3 | doo | 33 | red |
| 3 | doo | 35 | blue |
| 4 | sue | 60 | blue |
| 4 | sue | 20 | red |

Current work around result which I then fix with python and pandas

```
SELECT names_table.name_id, name, value, type
CASE 
    WHEN type = 'red' THEN value END red,
CASE 
    WHEN type = 'blue' THEN value END blue
FROM names_table
FULL OUTER JOIN values_table
ON names_table.name_id = values_table.name_id
```

| name_id | name | blue | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | Null | 90 |
| 2 | bar | 95 | Null |
| 3 | doo | 35 | Null |
| 3 | doo | Null | 33 |
| 4 | sue | 60 | Null |
| 4 | sue | Null | 20 |

This is my desired output below, where I would have the types as columns and just rows for unique name_ids but with value tables 1 and 2.

Desired Output

| name_id | name | blue | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | Null | 90 |
| 2 | bar | 95 | Null |
| 3 | doo | 35 | 33 |
| 4 | sue | 60 | 20 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two tables that I'd like do a `full outer join` ...

Why would you? Better explain what you actually want to do instead of the assumed tool to implement it.

Simple pivoting with the aggregate `FILTER` clause. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

```sql
SELECT name_id, n.name, v.blue, v.red
FROM  (
   SELECT name_id
        , min(value) FILTER (WHERE type = 'blue') AS blue
        , min(value) FILTER (WHERE type = 'red')  AS red
   FROM   values_table
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) v
LEFT   JOIN names_table n USING (name_id);
```

Produces your desired result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d08c00e5f3a3adf7e541a15630dcae13)*

The `LEFT JOIN` includes result rows even if no name is found.
A `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` would add names in the result that have no values at all. I think you really want a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` or even a plain `[INNER] JOIN`.

You can just switch the `JOIN` type to adapt to your actual requirements. The identical column name "name_id" allows to join with a `USING` clause. The unqualified `name_id` in the outer `SELECT` works for any join type.

Note how I aggregate first and join later. Typically substantially faster. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

If there can be duplicate values for "red" or "blue", you'll have to define how to deal with those.

For more involved queries consider `crosstab()`. See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I wanted to add the second table would I do a LEFT JOIN within the sub-query after FROM value_table, I would add 

LEFT JOIN value_table_2 USING (name_id) GROUP BY 1?

Comment: Depends on your intentions. Maybe `FROM names_table LEFT JOIN (<subquery 1>) USING (name_id) LEFT JOIN (<subquery 2>) USING (name_id)` or `FROM (<subquery 1>) FULL JOIN (<subquery 2>) USING (name_id) LEFT JOIN names_table USING (name_id)`.