# PostgreSQL subquery COUNT fails when the subquery is joined more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate

I have 2 tables:

Table `class`:

```
id serial4 PRIMARY KEY
name varchar(64)
code varchar(64)
```

Table `class_event`, where I store events related to classes, such as "started" and "ended".

```
id serial4
class_id int4 NOT NULL  // ->  FK to the class table
event_type varchar(1) NOT NULL  // -> 's' for started, 'e' for ended.
```

I need a query the amount of times each class has been started and ended. This works:

```
select
    c.code,
    c.name,
    count(started.id) "started"
from "class" c
left join (select id, class_id, event_type from "class_event" where event_type = 's') started 
    on started.klass_id = c.id
group by c.code, c.name
order by started desc;
```

But when I do exactly the same to get the amount of ended classes it shows incorrect amounts:

```
select
    c.code,
    c.name,
    count(started.id) "started",
    count(ended.id) "ended"
from "class" c
left join (select id, class_id, event_type from "class_event" where event_type = 's') started 
    on started.klass_id = c.id
left join (select id, class_id, event_type from "class_event" where event_type = 'e') ended 
    on ended.klass_id = c.id
group by c.code, c.name
order by started desc;
```

Also, the query takes significantly more time to execute. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything I'm missing?

Yes, multiple joins multiply rows. It's exactly the same problem as discussed here:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

While you query the whole table it's typically cleaner and faster to aggregate first and join later. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

This also avoids the original problem on principle, even for multiple joins - which we don't need.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   class c
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT class_id AS id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 's') AS started
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'e') AS ended
   FROM   class_event
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e  USING (id)
ORDER  BY e.started DESC NULLS LAST;
```

`NULLS LAST` because it's conceivable that some of the classes have no related rows in table `class_event` (yet), and the resulting `NULL` values surely shouldn't sort on top. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)
- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

Aside:

For just a hand full of allowed values, I would consider the data type `"char"` instead of `varchar(1)` for `event_type`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggregate function

```
select
    c.code,
    c.name,
    count(CASE WHEN event_type = 's' THEN ended.id END) "started",
    count(CASE WHEN event_type = 'e' THEN ended.id END) "ended"
from "class" c
left join "class_event" started 
    on started.class_id = c.id
group by c.code, c.name
order by started desc;
```

Comment: Use: `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 's')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes `Filter` is more Efficient