# What is the difference between direct addition (1 + 1) vs aggregate function SUM(1 + 1)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

See the query below where I get the reputation value from direct addition without a function.

```
SELECT
    "User"."id",
    "User"."name",
    "User"."title",
    "User"."about",
    "User"."location",
    "User"."isModerator",
    "User"."createdAt",
    (
--      question vote
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 10) FILTER (WHERE "value" = 1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NULL), 0)::int 
        +
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 2) FILTER (WHERE "value" = -1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NULL), 0)::int 
        +
--      answer vote
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 10) FILTER (WHERE "value" = 1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NOT NULL), 0)::int 
        +
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 2) FILTER (WHERE "value" = -1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NOT NULL), 0)::int 
        +
--      accepted answer
        (COALESCE(COUNT("answer"."id"), 0)::int * 15)
    ) as reputation
FROM "User"
LEFT JOIN "Post" ON "Post"."authorId" = "User"."id"
LEFT JOIN "PostVote" ON "PostVote"."postId" = "Post"."id"
LEFT JOIN "Post" as answer ON "Post"."acceptedAnswerId" = "answer"."id"
GROUP BY "User"."id"
ORDER BY reputation DESC, id
```

I did this because SUM cannot be nested, I originally wanted to do something like this.

```sql
-- ...
    SUM(
--      question vote
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 10) FILTER (WHERE "value" = 1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NULL), 0)::int 
        +
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 2) FILTER (WHERE "value" = -1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NULL), 0)::int 
        +
--      answer vote
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 10) FILTER (WHERE "value" = 1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NOT NULL), 0)::int 
        +
        COALESCE(SUM("PostVote"."value" * 2) FILTER (WHERE "value" = -1 AND "Post"."questionId" IS NOT NULL), 0)::int 
        +
--      accepted answer
        (COALESCE(COUNT("answer"."id"), 0)::int * 15)
    ) as reputation
-- ...
```

I'm curious if there are any performance impacts or summations that might potentially result in incorrect values? I have tested with negative values and it works fine, maybe there is something I missed.

I could have used the SUM function by nesting the queries, but I thought this would be too verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could have used the SUM function by nesting the queries ...

No you couldn't have. You are missing the fundamental difference between an aggregate function ([`sum()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)) and a plain operator ([`+`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)). [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)'s answer already goes into detail.

But since you expressed concern for performance impacts: you can optimize your use of `count()` which *never* returns `null`. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Assuming referential integrity, there is no need to actually join to the accepted answer. Just count not-null values in `p."acceptedAnswerId"`. (I am not convinced you are counting "accepts" correctly in the first place, but I stuck to your logic.)

Actually looks like you can replace all instances of `sum()` with a faster `count()`. Consequently, you need no `COALESCE` at all:

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.title, u.about, u.location, u."isModerator", u."createdAt"
     ,( -- q & a upvote
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE pv."value" =  1)::int * 10
       -- q & a downvote 
     + count(*) FILTER (WHERE pv."value" = -1)::int * -2
       -- accepted answer
     + count(p."acceptedAnswerId")::int * 15  -- cheaper
      ) AS reputation
FROM   "User"          u
LEFT   JOIN "Post"     p  ON p."authorId" = u.id
LEFT   JOIN "PostVote" pv ON pv."postId" = p.id
-- LEFT JOIN "Post"     a  ON a.id = p."acceptedAnswerId"  -- noise?! 
GROUP  BY u.id
ORDER  BY reputation DESC, u.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me understand concretely through the code. I've updated the code, removing the `createdAt` filtering. Do you have any suggestions if I want to sort reputation in the last week, this is similar to StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users, what do you think if we apply filtering for each "FILTER" like this (last week) `FILTER (WHERE pv."value" = 1 AND p."questionId" IS NULL AND p."createdAt" > '2023-12-23')`?

Comment: @R.M.Reza: I simplified accordingly. For "reputation in the last week", and outer `WHERE` clause applying overall is typically much more efficient: `WHERE p."createdAt" > '2023-12-23'`. *I guess* - not knowing your relational model.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. For the model, I think the key is in the "PostVote" table, I defined a combined unique constraint between `postId` and `userId`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that SUM is an aggregation function — its argument is a single expression, which is evaluated for each relevant row, and it gives the sum of all of the results (or NULL if there were no results) — whereas `+` is a normal binary operator: it appears inside an expression, its operands are two subexpressions, and for any given row, it gives the sum of what the two subexpressions give.

Additionally, they handle NULLs a bit differently; `+` gives NULL when either subexpression gives NULL, whereas SUM skips over NULLs (and returns NULL only if it receives *no* non-NULL values).

I don't think it's meaningful to discuss relative performance, since they're used in very different ways, so there are no queries that differ in using one vs. the other.