# Query does not show current month's data

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
       COALESCE(SUM(dm.revenue)::FLOAT, 0.0) AS total_amount,
       COALESCE(COUNT(dm.id), 0) AS value,
       array_agg(dm.id) AS lost_deal_ids
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '4 months', DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL '1 month')::DATE AS month
) months
LEFT JOIN deal_management dm ON TO_CHAR(dm.closing_date, 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') AND dm.employee_id = 'sojdosdj2920320323'
LEFT JOIN lookup_data ld ON ld.id = dm.pipeline_id
WHERE (TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '4 months', 'YYYY-MM') AND TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
    OR TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM'))
    AND (ld.level_data = 'Lost' OR ld.id IS NULL)
    AND dm.is_evaluate IS NOT TRUE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(months.month, 'YYYY-MM');
```

[demo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns0Mt.png)

I want to see current month's data as

```
 2024-01 | 0 | {null}
```

But if missing want to see '0'.

Comment: Assuming `NULL` will always be the only element: `select coalesce(('{null}'::char[])[0], '0'); 0`. Then: `... coalesce((array_agg(dm.id))[0], '0') AS lost_deal_ids`

Comment: Thank you Adrian, But still not showing current month's data.

Comment: Please post textual details as inline formatted text and not as images or links to images. Please see [ask]. Include table DDL, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Don't convert dates to character strings and then compare them: doing so adds unnecessary verbosity, obscures the code's intent, and is less efficient than directly operating on the native date type. The first `OR` expression in the `WHERE` clause is unnecessary: if the current date's month is equal to the generated series' month, then the `BETWEEN` expression must also be true.

Comment: Thank you JohnH, I fixed it. Yes The OR in WHERE was unnecessary.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every aspect of your query needs attention. This might work, and a lot faster, too:

```sql
SELECT to_char(m.mon, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
     , coalesce(sum(dm.revenue)::float, 0.0) AS total_amount
     , count(dm.id) AS count_deals
     , coalesce(string_agg(dm.id::text, ', '), '0') AS lost_deal_ids
FROM   generate_series(date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP) - interval '4 mon'
                     , date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP)
                     , interval '1 month') m(mon)
LEFT   JOIN deal_management dm ON dm.closing_date >= m.mon
                              AND dm.closing_date <  m.mon + interval '1 mon'
                              AND dm.employee_id = 'sojdosdj2920320323'
                              AND dm.is_evaluate IS NOT TRUE
LEFT   JOIN lookup_data     ld ON ld.id = dm.pipeline_id
                              AND ld.level_data = 'Lost'
GROUP  BY m.mon
ORDER  BY m.mon;
```

If you want to see '0' instead of null, you can't use an array type for the output column `lost_deal_ids`. Use `string_agg()` instead of `array_agg()`. (Why bother, though? You count is clear anyway.)

The table-function `generate_series()` can stand on its own in the `FROM` list after we remove the unhelpful cast to `date`.

Use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`. This way, `date_trunc()` produces `timestamp` instead of `timestamptz`. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

To put it bluntly, none of your `WHERE` conditions make sense.

- This is 100 % redundant. Twice redundant actually. The 1st boolean expressions is always true, the 2nd is implied by the first:

  ```
    WHERE (to_char(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') BETWEEN to_char(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '4 months', 'YYYY-MM') AND to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
    OR to_char(months.month, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM'))
  ```
- This is an awkward, inferior way of adding `ld.level_data = 'Lost'` as join condition to the `LEFT JOIN`:

  ```
    WHERE (ld.level_data = 'Lost' OR ld.id IS NULL)
  ```
- This would contradict the `LEFT JOIN`. (I resolved by moving it into the join condition):

  ```
    WHERE  dm.is_evaluate IS NOT TRUE
  ```

`count()` never returns `null`. So `coalesce(count( ...` never does anything useful.

Understand the different role of conditions in `WHERE` vs. `LEFT JOIN`:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Your join condition `ON to_char(dm.closing_date, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(months.month, 'YYYY-MM')` was needlessly expensive. And not [saragable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Use the sargable expression `ON dm.closing_date >= m.mon AND dm.closing_date < m.mon + interval '1 mon'` instead.

Use the timestamp value, not the text generated with `to_char()` in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Cheaper, and less error prone.

Don't use a non-descriptive column alias like "value".

Consider hiring a consultant.