# Query with LEFT Join SQL crashes after taking too long

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wish to display the number of transactions a vendor has made in each system. I have a problem with the query below.

Database: PostgreSQL 13

```
SELECT 
v.code, v.name, 
COALESCE(transactionA.transactionA_count, 0) AS transactionA_count,
COALESCE(transactionB.transactionB_count, 0) AS transactionB_count,
COALESCE(transactionC.transactionC_count, 0) AS transactionC_count
FROM vendors as v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT code, COUNT(id) AS transactionA_count
    FROM transactionA
    GROUP BY code
) transactionA ON transactionA.code = v.code
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT code, COUNT(id) AS transactionB_count
    FROM transactionB
    GROUP BY code
) transactionB ON transactionB.code = v.code
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT code, COUNT(id) AS transactionC_count
    FROM transactionC
    GROUP BY code
) transactionC ON transactionC.code = v.code
WHERE transactionA.transactionA_count IS NULL
  AND transactionB.transactionB_count IS NULL
  AND transactionC.transactionC_count IS NULL
```

Each transaction table has more than 100,000 rows.
CPU utilization 100% after executing.

Comment: What is the actual execution plan for this query?

Comment: Display the vendor and transaction count for each transaction table in a single row.

Comment: Please explain "crashes after taking too long"  Which error does it return? And what is _too long_  ?

Comment: Why do you have IS NULL on each count, in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres should not crash under any circumstances. So there are more problems lurking.
Addressing the elephant in the room, which is a highly inefficient query.

You state:
*"I wish to display the number of transactions a vendor has made in each system."*

But then you show a (highly inefficient) query that only shows vendors without any transactions in systems A, B, and C. There is no point in doing expensive counts, just to throw them away afterwards. (Assuming all `id` columns are `NOT NULL`.) Your query burns down to this 100 % equivalent:

```sql
SELECT v.code, v.name
     , 0 AS transactionA_count  -- just noise
     , 0 AS transactionB_count  -- just noise
     , 0 AS transactionC_count  -- just noise
FROM   vendors v
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM transactionA a WHERE a.code = v.code)
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM transactionB b WHERE b.code = v.code)
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM transactionC c WHERE c.code = v.code);
```

OTOH, to only show vendors that have made any transactions in one of the 3 systems:

```sql
SELECT v.code, v.name
     , COALESCE(a.ct, 0) AS transactionA_count
     , COALESCE(b.ct, 0) AS transactionB_count
     , COALESCE(c.ct, 0) AS transactionC_count
FROM   vendors v
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT code, count(*) AS ct FROM transactionA GROUP BY 1) a USING (code)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT code, count(*) AS ct FROM transactionB GROUP BY 1) b USING (code)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT code, count(*) AS ct FROM transactionC GROUP BY 1) c USING (code)
WHERE (a.code IS NOT NULL
    OR b.code IS NOT NULL
    OR c.code IS NOT NULL);
```

The second can be substantially more expensive. Either way, be sure to have an index with `code` as leading or only field for `transactionA`, B & C to make it fast.

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

The aggregate function `count()` never returns null by itself. See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Aside: avoid CaMeL-case identifier in Postgres if you can. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: I appreciate the information and advice you have shared.