# ServiceStack OrmLite LeftJoin Issue

Tags: sql, servicestack, left-join, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack OrmLite JoinSQLBuilder with a left join and have found an issue.
Suppose I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB and wanted to join on more than a single value.

In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT  
    TableA.Name, 
    TableB.Value
FROM    
    TableA
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB 
ON     
    TableB.AId = TableA.Id
    AND TableB.PostCode = '12345'
```

Now the JoinSQLBuilder only allows joins on a single column and generates SQL like so

```
SELECT  
    TableA.Name, 
    TableB.Value
FROM    
    TableA
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB 
ON     
    TableB.AId = TableA.Id
WHERE
    TableB.PostCode = '12345'
```

Which is not the same thing at all!

Is there any way around this in ServiceStack OrmLite?
Here is an example of left joins with where clauses: [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [new support for JOIN's in OrmLite's Typed SqlExpressions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins). 
It's best to use the latest [v4.0.23 release on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) which includes improved support for [selecting multiple columns across joined tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#selecting-multiple-columns-across-joined-tables).

With the new JOIN API's you can do what you need with something like:

```
public class TableA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class TableABFields
{
    public string TableAName { get; set; }
    public string TableBValue { get; set; }
}

var results = db.Select<TableABFields,TableA>(q =>
    q.Join<TableA,TableB>((a,b) => b.AId == a.Id && b.PostCode == "12345"));
```

Alternative API using an [explicit SQL Expression](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins):

```
var q = db.From<TableA>();
// or 
var q = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SqlExpression<TableA>();


q.Join<TableA,TableB>((a,b) => b.AId == a.Id && b.PostCode == "12345");

var results = db.Select(q);
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to build up a predicate without needing the "db" to join onto. For example, build the join in a repository layer before passing it to the data access. db.Join<TableABFields>(predicate);

Comment: Thanks for that - I've got the layers working well. After updating to the latest version though, I get the error "Method not found: 'Void ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1..ctor()'." on a call from connection.Single<T>(x => x.Id == id && x.IsDeleted == false);

Comment: @ByronCobb that's indicative of a dirty version mismatch issue. I've just [Created a new Console App for this](https://gist.github.com/mythz/2fd115956d57bb684787) using the [MyGet package](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) and it works as expected. Make sure all your packages were updated, otherwise I'd do a clean reinstall of all ServiceStack packages.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I keep finding more though - should I start a new question? It doesn't seem that I can use inherited class values anymore => TableA : BaseEntity => BaseEntity.IsDeleted = 

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Unknown column 'BaseEntity.IsDeleted' in 'where clause'

Comment: @ByronCobb yeah can you open up a new question with the exception and source code that creates the error.

Comment: thank you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431135/servicestack-ormlite-joins-on-child-classes