# ServiceStack Ormlite - Joins on child classes

Tags: c#, join, ormlite-servicestack, mysql.data

I'm using the latest ServiceStack Ormlite (v4.0.23), which provides new join support for joining on multiple columns.

My entities all inherit from a BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
  [AutoIncrement]
  [PrimaryKey]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public DateTime Created { get; set; }

  public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

  public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have 2 entities, UserEntity and AnswerEntity, which inherit from this base class.
When using the JoinSqlBuilder in v4.0.19 I could join these using something like this:

```
var joinBuilder = new JoinSqlBuilder<AnswerEntity, UserEntity>();

joinBuilder = joinBuilder.Join<AnswerEntity, UserEntity>(
  l => l.UserId,
  r => r.Id,
  x => new { x.Id, x.AnswerValue, x.QuestionId, x.Created, x.Updated, x.Deleted, x.IsDeleted },
  null,
  lx => lx.IsDeleted == false,
  rx => rx.IsDeleted == false);
```

After updating, I get the error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Unknown column 'BaseEntity.IsDeleted'
>   in 'where clause'    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId)...

Using the new join support, I get the same error:

```
expression.Join<AnswerEntity, UserEntity>((l, r) => l.UserId == r.Id);
expression.Where<AnswerEntity>(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should now be resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d0a75e0357d32f0155b92bbf79161c0f81e2965d) that's available from **v4.0.23+** of ServiceStack that's [currently available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). If you have existing **v4.0.23** packages from MyGet installed it will need to be uninstalled first to be able to pull down the updated packages.