# LEFT JOIN gives different data set depending on the position of WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

See the below 3 Counts, just to give you a brief idea about the table data. All `skCitizen` in `[dbo].[LUEducation]` is present in `[dbo].[LUCitizen]`

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM   [dbo].[LUCitizen] --115000 ROWS
SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM   [dbo].[LUEducation]  --201846 ROWS

SELECT  COUNT(*) --212695 ROWS
FROM    [dbo].[LUCitizen] C
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[LUEducation] E
ON      C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen

SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM   [dbo].[LUEducation] WHERE skSchool = 24417 --4 ROWS
```

---

See the below 2 queries,

```
SELECT  C.skCitizen,E.skCitizen
FROM    [dbo].[LUCitizen] C
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[LUEducation] E
ON      C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen
WHERE   E.skSchool = 24417
--4 ROWS

SELECT  C.skCitizen,E.skCitizen
FROM    [dbo].[LUCitizen] C
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LUEducation] WHERE skSchool = 24417) E
ON      C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen
--115000 ROWS
```

In the last 2 queries, the confusing query for me is the 1st one. There i expected `115000 rows`, but only `4 rows` displayed.
According to my understanding, Full rows from `[dbo].[LUCitizen]` will be displayed, then 4 rows from `[dbo].[LUEducation]` will be `LEFT` Joined.

**Why is the 2 Queries different?**

Pardon me , if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: That's because the one returning 4 rows is implicitly converting into a regular `(INNER) JOIN`.  After the `LEFT JOIN`, there's a bunch of rows where `e.skSchool IS NULL`; since `null <> 24417`, it throws those out.... there has to be a duplicate for this somewhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left Join With Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: You're right about the rows, but it's not correct to say that `null <> 24417`.  The result of `true <> 24417` is `unknown`, which is [neither `true` nor `false`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

Comment: @Andomar - you're right, that's a more nuanced version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `left join` fails to find a match in `E`, columns from `E` receive a `null` value.  Then the `where` clause:

```
E.skSchool = 24417
```

Becomes:

```
null = 24417
```

Which is not true.  So it will filter out all rows.

Answer (score 8):

When you do this:

```
SELECT  C.skCitizen,E.skCitizen
FROM    [dbo].[LUCitizen] C
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[LUEducation] E
ON      C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen
WHERE   E.skSchool = 24417;
```

You are turning the `left join` into an `inner join`, because `E.skSchool` is `NULL` for non-matching rows.  The correct way to put a condition on the *second* table in a `left join` is to use the `on` clause:

```
SELECT  C.skCitizen,E.skCitizen
FROM    [dbo].[LUCitizen] C
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[LUEducation] E
ON      C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen AND E.skSchool = 24417;
```

Comment: @HHH . . . This should be covered in any book teaching SQL joins.