# Linking 3 tables with a Left Outer Join

Tags: sqlite, join, left-join, outer-join

I have 3 tables in a SQLite database for an Android app. This picture below shows the relevant tables that I'm working with.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04kbq.jpg)

I'm trying to get two fields, value and name, from measurement_lines and competences respectively, tied to a specific person_id in measurements. I'm trying to make a query that returns these fields but I'm having little luck. The best I've got so far is the following query:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM measurements, measurement_lines, competences
WHERE measurements.id = measurement_lines.measurements_id
AND measurement_lines.competences_id = competences.id
AND measurements.persons_id = 1
```

This, however, has one issue. This query won't return any records when a person has no entries in measurements (and subsequently, nothing in measurement_lines). What I want is to always get a list of competence names, even if the value column is empty. I'm guessing I need a Left Outer Join for this but I can't seem to make it work. The following query just returns no records:

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM measurements AS m, competences AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN measurement_lines AS ml ON c._id = ml.competence_id   
WHERE ml.measurement_id = m._id AND m.persons_id = 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inner joins, you can be sloppy with the distinction between join conditions and selection predicates, but when outer joins are involved that makes a difference.  Any criterion appearing in the `WHERE` clause filters your result rows *after* all joins are performed (logically, at least), which can remove result rows associated with outer tables.

In addition, if you're ever uncertain about join order, you can use parentheses to make your intent clear.  At least in many DBMSs.  It lokos like SQLite doesn't support them.

It looks like you may want this: (*edited to avoid use of parentheses*)

```
SELECT c.name, pm.value
FROM competences c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT ml.competences_id AS cid,
        ml.value AS value
      FROM measurement_lines ml
        INNER JOIN measurements m
        ON m.id = ml.measurements_id
      WHERE m.person_id = 1
  ) pm
  ON pm.cid = c.id
```

Comment: I keep getting a "no such column" at ml.competences_id. I believe it is caused by the parentheses as it does recognize ml.measurements_id

Comment: I updated it to a version that doesn't use parentheses, which is a bit tricky to get right.  I think I have it.  The `WHERE` clause selects result rows that match the specified person plus those where there is no measurement_line matching the competence at all.

Comment: I updated it again.  The new version uses a subquery (an uncorrelated one), which I think is necessary to get this right without grouping the joins directly.