# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN on 3 tables with a joining table in the middle

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Tables:

- IN
- OUT
- IN_OUT

I want all of the items from IN, and, if they exist in IN_OUT and OUT, the values from OUT.

```
SELECT intable.colA, outtable.colB 
from IN intable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IN_OUT inouttable ON inouttable.idin = intable.idin 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OUT outtable ON inouttable.idout = outtable.idout
```

This gives:

- 2 correct results with values from outtable (the IN "object" is present twice in INOUT, with corresponding values in OUT)
- But 1 more result line coming from nowhere, with a null value for the outtable column

I tried [Linking 3 tables with a Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806495/linking-3-tables-with-a-left-outer-join) with the same result:

```
SELECT intable.colA, outtable.colB 
FROM IN intable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT inouttable.idin, outtable.colB
    FROM IN_OUT inouttable, OUT outtable
    WHERE inouttable.idout = outtable.idout) out2
ON in.idin = out2.idin
```

What do I write?

IN

```
IDIN      COLA
1         ABC
2         DEF
```

OUT

```
IDOUT      COLA
1          XYZ
2          XYZ2
```

INOUT

```
IDIN    ID OUT
1       1
1       2
```

I want as a result:

```
COLA      COLB
ABC       XYZ
ABC       XYZ2
DEF       null
```

I get:

```
COLA      COLB
ABC       XYZ
ABC       XYZ2
ABC       null
DEF       null
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you've mocked your sample data and expected result correctly? https://dbfiddle.uk/zE7blcEZ your query seems spot on

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. What is needed to ask & only that should be in your post. Quote with credit from elsewhere & relate to your question. Don't expect readers to read entire other pages & guess what is relevant & why.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 2):

Use two LEFT [OUTER] JOINS:

```
SELECT 
   IN.COLA as ColA,
   OUT.COLA as ColB
FROM `IN`
LEFT JOIN IN_OUT ON IN.IDIN = IN_OUT.IDIN
LEFT JOIN `OUT` ON OUT.IDOUT = IN_OUT.IDOUT
ORDER BY IN.COLA, OUT.COLA
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/C3cV8TAN)

output:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ |
| ABC | XYZ2 |
| DEF | null |

P.S.:  It is advised to not use [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-I:%7E:text=and%20Reserved%20Words-,MySQL%208.0%20Keywords%20and%20Reserved%20Words,-The%20following%20list) as tablenames....

Comment: Thank you. This problem I'm facing for hours now is due to... (very) poorly made ids... Grrrr. I delete the question as the initial select I've made was OK.

Comment: Note that MySQL reserved words are not exactly the same as others. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 0):

This problem was poorly made ids.

Double/triple check your ids.

Comment: "poorly made ids" is not clear This is not useful.