# SQL LEFT JOIN WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with settingIDs and values of those settings for each userID and another with userIDs, their emails and user names.

I am trying to join the values of specific settings, the problem is that not all users have this specific setting tied to their ID, so I end up with less rows than I actually need.

```
Table 1
userID settingID settingValue

Table 2
userID userDOB userEmail userName
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userEmail, s.settingValue
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userSettings s ON u.userID = s.userID
WHERE s.settingID = 1
```

What do I need to do to  get all of the users in the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join With Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns you `left join` into an `inner join`. Put the condition in the JOIN

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userEmail, s.settingValue
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userSettings s ON u.userID = s.userID
                        AND s.settingID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UNION ALL` clause to combine two `JOINS`

```
SELECT  u.userID, u.userEmail, s.settingValue
     FROM users u
     LEFT userSettings s
     ON u.userID = s.userID
UNION ALL
     SELECT  u.userID, u.userEmail, s.settingValue
     FROM users u
     RIGHT userSettings s
     ON u.userID = s.userID
```