# Why is my t-sql left join not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you run this and tell me why the result set only has two rows. It should have three and look like this...

```
appId    stepId       section       start
101      1           Section 1     2016-01-03 00:00:00.000
101      2           Section 2     2016-01-03 00:00:00.000
101      10          Section 3     NULL
```

Here is the sql so you can just paste it into your query tool

```
create table #appSteps(stepId decimal, section nvarchar(50))
insert into #appSteps (stepId, section) values (1, 'Section 1')
insert into #appSteps (stepId, section) values (2, 'Section 2')
insert into #appSteps (stepId, section) values (3, null)
insert into #appSteps (stepId, section) values (4, null)
insert into #appSteps (stepId, section) values (10, 'Section 3')

create table #appProgress(stepId decimal, appId int, start datetime)
insert into #appProgress (stepId, appId, start) values (1, 101, '1/3/2016')
insert into #appProgress (stepId, appId, start) values (2, 101, '1/3/2016')
insert into #appProgress (stepId, appId, start) values (3, 101, '1/3/2016')
insert into #appProgress (stepId, appId, start) values (4, 101, '1/3/2016')


select p.appId, s.stepId, s.section, p.start
from #appSteps s with (nolock)
left join #appProgress p on s.stepId = p.stepId
where s.section is not null
and p.appId = 101

drop table #appSteps
drop table #appProgress
```

I cannot figure out why all 3 non null rows from #appSteps are not coming back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason is because you are including the right-hand table in the `WHERE` clause.  You should move that to the `ON` condition of the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select    P.appId, S.stepId, S.section, P.start
From      #appSteps    S   With (NoLock)
Left Join #appProgress P   On  S.stepId = P.stepId 
                           And P.appId = 101
Where     S.section Is Not Null
```

The reason it does this is because the `WHERE` clause is evaluated *after* the `LEFT JOIN`, which then filters out your `NULL` results from the `LEFT JOIN`.

Including the right-hand table of a `LEFT JOIN` (or the left-hand table of a `RIGHT JOIN`) in the `WHERE` clause effectively transforms the `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Siyual Good explanation as well.

Comment: @Siyal, many searches did not contain this vital information. Thank you!!!

Comment: I had been pulling my hair for this. Thank you for the explanation!