# T-SQL left join not returning null columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables in T-SQL one with 10 records and one with 11.

```
select tbl.unit, tbl2.unid 
from tbl1
left join tbl2 on tbl2.UNID = tbl1.UNIT
where tbl2.Status = 'Main'
group by unit, UNID
```

This only returns 10 records when tbl1 has 11 records. I was expecting the missing record to show a value if UNIT but null for UNID but is just is not there.

I cannot figure out why this is the case

Comment: Well 'Main' doesn't equal NULL, so why would you expect that record to return in your results?

Comment: Move `tbl2.Status = 'Main'` to your `ON`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my t-sql left join not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093809/why-is-my-t-sql-left-join-not-working) (Can't gold badge as I added the tag.)

Comment: Per dfundako and lamu, above: SELECT tbl.unit
  , tbl2.unid
FROM tbl1
  LEFT JOIN tbl2
   ON tbl2.UNID = tbl1.UNIT
  AND tbl2.STATUS = 'Main'
GROUP BY unit
    , UNID;

Comment: As stated, you can move `tbl2.Status = 'Main'` to your `ON` or you can add `WHERE (tbl2.Status = 'Main' OR tbl2.Status IS NULL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So why would a `LEFT JOIN` not show all the records from a left side of the join.

Is a bug?

Most likely not.

Lets look at a simplified example.

TableA has 3 records.

```
ID    ColA
1     Foo
2     Bar
3     Buzz
```

TableB has 2 records

```
ID    ColB
4     Foo
5     Bar
```

An `INNER JOIN` on ColA & ColB would return 2 records.
Only those where a match  is found.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.ColB = a.ColA
```

Returns:

```
ColA    ColB
Foo     Foo
Bar     Bar
```

A `LEFT JOIN` would return 3 records.
With a `NULL` on the right side for the unmatched.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.ColB = a.ColA
```

Returns:

```
ColA    ColB
Foo     Foo
Bar     Bar
Buzz    null
```

But what happens if a criteria is used in the `WHERE` clause for the right side?

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.ColB = a.ColA
WHERE b.ColB IN ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Buzz')
```

Returns:

```
ColA    ColB
Foo     Foo
Bar     Bar
```

What? Where's the 'Buzz'?

Can you guess why that `LEFT JOIN` seems to behave like an `INNER JOIN`?

The solution is to put such criteria in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b 
   ON b.ColB = a.ColA AND b.ColB IN ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Buzz')
```

Or do put the criteria in the `WHERE`, but also allow `NULL`.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b 
   ON b.ColB = a.ColA
WHERE (b.ColB IN ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Buzz') 
       OR b.ColB IS NULL)
```

Returns:

```
ColA    ColB
Foo     Foo
Bar     Bar
Buzz    null
```

Now the Buzz is back.