# Ignore WHERE clause when column value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * from A JOIN B on B.refId = A.id
WHERE B.restriction = 123
```

I would like to change the behaviour as follows:

- If `B.restriction` exists, the query acts like the above
- If `B.restriction` is `NULL` (or possibly some specified 'magic' value) the clause is ignored

Is there a short, neat way to do this that doesn't rely on `IF/ELSE` type logic? I'm specifically using SqlServer (2012 at the oldest).

To clarify, it *is* allowed for `B.restriction` to be `Null`. A restriction can be added but if not specified, shouldn't get in the way hence wanting to 'ignore' the `where` clause.

Comment: That isn't how SQL works. If you want `NULL` values too you need to use an `OR` and an addition clause to check if the value `IS NULL`.

Comment: I feel this must be a dupe but Idon't know what to google

Comment: Is it actually the column `B.restriction` is `NULL`, or is it that actually, there was no row found from the table `B`?

Comment: @Larnu the row exists but no `restriction` has been set. If a restriction exists it must be observed but if not, we match all results. Slightly clunky client data for optional restrictions where we don't know all the possible values :)

Comment: I had been wondering if some sort of `NVL` type magic might work but I can't wrap my head around it (yes I know NVL is Oracle)

Comment: It's ill advised to use `ISNULL` (SQL Server's equivilent to `NVL`) on a column in your `WHERE`, as that would cause the query to be non-SARGable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my t-sql left join not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093809/why-is-my-t-sql-left-join-not-working) Move the condition to the `ON` clause

Comment: The linked question _might_ be about a similar issue but it is at best the same answer to a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what the question you are *actually* asking is.

If the column `restriction` in the table `B` can be `NULL`, but a row found, you need to use an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.A
     JOIN dbo.B ON B.refId = A.id
WHERE B.restriction = 123
   OR B.restriction IS NULL;
```

If actually what you want is for when rows aren't found but you only want rows where the value of `restriction` is `123` then use a `LEFT JOIN` and migrate the clause in your `WHERE` to the `JOIN`'s `ON`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.A
     LEFT JOIN dbo.B ON B.RefId = A.id
                    AND B.restriction = 123;
```

Comment: I've clarified in the question, thanks for pointing out this ambiguity.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, @Mr.Boy , however, by the time the comment came in I'd basically written the answer, and I felt there was little harm leaving details for both scenarios.

Comment: no problem with that :)