# How to only run left join when the variable is not null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to simplify my stored procedure and I have one that is only using left join based on the user id that is passed in. If the user id is null, don't do left join, but if it is null, left join it with another table. How should I re-write it ? Thank you

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRoom] 
    @RoomId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN   
    IF (@UserId IS NULL)
    BEGIN   
        SELECT r.Id, r.DisplayName            
        FROM Room r
        INNER JOIN Game g ON r.GameId = g.Id
        INNER JOIN ProfileDuplicated pd ON r.HostedById = pd.Id                         
        WHERE r.Id = @RoomId
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT 
            r.Id, r.DisplayName, 
            ru.Description, -- this is coming from the left join table
            ru.Tags         -- from left join table   
        FROM Room r
        INNER JOIN Game g ON r.GameId = g.Id
        INNER JOIN ProfileDuplicated pd ON r.HostedById = pd.Id          
        LEFT JOIN RoomUser ru ON ru.RoomId = r.Id
        WHERE r.Id = @RoomId AND ru.UserId = @UserId
END
```

Comment: With `ru.UserId = @UserId` at the `WHERE` clause, you are effectively doing a `INNER JOIN` to `RoomUser`, not a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my t-sql left join not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093809/why-is-my-t-sql-left-join-not-working)

Comment: There is simply NO REASON to provide a default value of NULL for your first parameter. That is just nonsense and your query will return nothing in that situation. Don't encourage lazy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your stored procedure return different number columns depending on the  `@UserId`.

You may remove the `IF` condition, and combined it as one single query by moving `ru.UserId = @UserId` to `ON` condition. This will make it a true `LEFT JOIN` to table `RoomUser`.

This will means it always return 4 columns as result

```
    SELECT r.Id, 
           r.DisplayName, 
           ru.Description,
           ru.Tags        
    FROM   Room r
           INNER JOIN Game g               ON r.GameId     = g.Id
           INNER JOIN ProfileDuplicated pd ON r.HostedById = pd.Id          
           LEFT JOIN RoomUser ru           ON ru.RoomId    = r.Id
                                          AND ru.UserId    = @UserId
    WHERE  r.Id = @RoomId
```

Comment: It works. Awesome. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below,

```
        SELECT 
            r.Id, r.DisplayName, 
            ru.Description, -- this is coming from the left join table
            ru.Tags         -- from left join table   
        FROM Room r
        INNER JOIN Game g ON r.GameId = g.Id
        INNER JOIN ProfileDuplicated pd ON r.HostedById = pd.Id          
        LEFT JOIN RoomUser ru ON ru.RoomId = r.Id  
                              AND r.Id IS NOT NULL 
                              AND r.Id = @RoomId 
                              AND ru.UserId IS NOT NULL
                              AND ru.UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: Those `IS NOT NULL` checks are redundant, the `=` will do that anyway. The key is moving the conditions to the `ON` instead of `WHERE`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks to highlight :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL` function to check the `NULL` value of the parameter. (Assuming `ru.userId` will not be `NULL`)

```
WHERE r.Id = @RoomId AND 
ru.UserId = ISNULL(@UserId, ru.UserId)
```