# Join tables with condition in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

How can I build query in Crystal Report with additional condition? Something like this:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID 
             AND T2.ID = value
```

I wrote in general terms because I meant exactly this query syntax and table join, i.e. an additional join condition. The query I am working on is quite complicated and has a WHERE clause. What I meant by saying that the `WHERE` clause doesn't work is that the syntax is:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID 
WHERE T2.ID = value
```

doesn't work. I want to select certain values from the database that are assigned to the document element in the ERP system (attributes). There are 3 attributes assigned to one element. Record:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID 
             AND T2.ID = value
```

allows you to select single lines instead of three. Of course, table T2 will be repeated two more times with appropriate aliases. Sample query:

```
SELECT d.docNo, e.product, a1.atr1, a2.atr2, a3.atr3 
FROM docs d 
INNER JOIN elem e ON d.id = e.doc_id 
LEFT JOIN attributes a1 ON e.id = a1.e_id AND a1. a_id = 2 
LEFT JOIN attributes a2 ON e.id = a2.e_id AND a2.a_id = 3 
LEFT JOIN attributes a3 ON e.id = a3.e_id AND a3.a_id = 4 
WHERE d.id = 123
```

SQL accepts such queries and can display appropriately formatted data. How to use such a structure in Crystal Reports?

Comment: Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77507662/861716) was marked as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40093809/861716). Then you deleted it and re-posted it. Please keep in mind that that's considered bad practice on Stack Overflow. If you don't agree with the closure, you should edit your question, telling why the duplicate doesn't apply, and vote to reopen. In this question you still don't explain what "doesn't work" means, which makes me think that the duplicate is actually appropriate.

Comment: Also, "How to use such a structure in Crystal Reports?" is an entirely different question, which requires a lot more background. Please put that in another question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use a database ***View*** or ***Stored Procedure*** as the data source for the report. A close second is to use a Crystal Reports ***Command*** as the data source.

There are a couple of other options but, for most use cases, the options above are the best.