# Rails - Has many, with query get all nested and parent object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have been working on an scheduling app, and running into an issue with finding a way to efficiently get specific records.

Here are the models in question.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
 belongs_to :project, optional: true
 belongs_to :project_schedule, optional: true
 belongs_to :user_schedule, optional: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
 include Filterable
 validates :email, presence: true
 validates :email, uniqueness: true
 has_many :tasks
```

What the front end expects is a json of all users, with all tasks nested within them. This has become too cumbersome to load that many tasks and I was attempting to specify a date range to the tasks while still getting all users.

So this seems more difficult that I originally expected. I can get all users efficiently, all tasks within a date range, and all users with tasks within a given date range with the tasks included. But getting all users with the tasks nested within a given date range has evaded me.

What I've tried

```
User.filter(params.slice(:project_ids, :email, :id))
 .includes(:tasks).where('((tasks.end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
 OR (tasks.start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?))',
 week_start, week_end, week_start, week_end)
 .references(:tasks).order(:name)
```

I've also tried merging all users and all users with tasks within the range to no avail.

I feel like key is raw SQL but I couldn't wrap my head around the query yesterday.

Any insight would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with that query? Is your goal "All Users" and just load the tasks in a given range? (Outer Join with condition) If so maybe just execute 2 queries (one for users and one for tasks in the date range) then just unify them in the UI. What rails version are you using as well as rails 5 offers `left_joins` as well as `or` syntax options?

Comment: The issue with the query is I only get the users with tasks within the date range, when my UI expects a list of all users.

As for version, I am using rails 5.


As for unifying them on the UI that's what I am currently trying. I thought it would prove difficult to line up the tasks with the correct user, when I first considered this route.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a left outer join. However, if you have a `WHERE` clause, this will filter away results for which the join fails, see [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause]).

You need to specify the condition as part of the `JOIN` clause, so something along these lines:

```
User.filter(params.slice(:project_ids, :email, :id))
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOINS tasks ON tasks.user_id = users.id AND 
            tasks.end_date BETWEEN :week_start AND :week_end OR 
            tasks.start_date BETWEEN :week_start AND 
            :week_end", week_start: week_start, week_end: week_end
    .includes(:tasks).order(:name)
```