# expected that this query will not output 0 values, but it does

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, left-join

I expected that this query will not output 0 values, but it does. I thought that `and (...) > 0` will not output 0 values. So how I can prevent the output of 0 values?

```
select lot.*, sum(movement.quantity) as value 
from lot
left join lot_movement as movement on lot.id = movement.lot_id
where lot.item_id = 8 and movement.storage_id = 3
and (select sum(lot_movement.quantity) 
    from lot_movement 
    where lot_movement.lot_id = lot.id
    ) > 0
group by lot.id;
```

I tried to add `and sum(lot_movement.quantity) \> 0`, but this gives error `invalid use of group function`.

[lots in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpnM2.png)

[lot_movements in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I9Nw.png)

[output with 0 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUSfD.png)

I see that

```
and (select sum(lot_movement.quantity)
    from lot_movement
    where lot_movement.lot_id = lot.id
    group by lot_movement.lot_id) > 0
```

is redundant. It doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text would be helpful. NB group by on one column whilst selecting all columns is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Change `lot.*` to `lot.id` share sample data. This was addressed in earlier comment, do not repeat question that you typed in the question when asking a question.

Comment: @DaniilShipilov: But it will prevent an error like "invalide use of group function"

Comment: The query in the link is not the same as the query published. Do take some time to make the question consistent. AND links are not useable whereas text is.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please: Backquote `\``is not single quote `'`. Look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. Spell check. Format code reasonably. Write a specific title.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't give the expected result because you're filtering by `lot.item_id = 8 and movement.storage_id = 3` in the `where` clause, but you're not applying that same filtering in the subselect.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect adding a `having` clause instead of the subselect solves your problem:

```
select lot.id, sum(movement.quantity) as value 
from lot
left join lot_movement as movement on lot.id = movement.lot_id
where lot.item_id = 8 and movement.storage_id = 3
group by lot.id
having sum(movement.quantity) > 0
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpfull. It's solving problem. Thank you very much