# Left join with multiple values in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, where-clause

[image]

I have two tables `broadcast` and `contact` and I want the count of the number of recipients in that particular broadcast if there is no user still all broadcast lists should be displayed. for this, I got my desired output with this left join Query.

```
SELECT b.id, b.brl_name, COUNT(c.broadcast_list_id) AS Recepients FROM broadcastlistsms b LEFT JOIN addcontact c ON b.id = c.broadcast_list_id GROUP BY b.id,b.brl_name;
```

But I have 2 common fields in both tables that are created_by and isdeleted, isdeleted(1) is that particular contact and broadcast is deleted. So I want to get only that contact count which is not deleted and created by a particular user. and similarly to broadcast, the broadcast should not be deleted and created by the particular user.

I tried this but it did not give broadcast entry which has 0 contacts.

```
SELECT b.id, b.brl_name, COUNT(c.broadcast_list_id) AS Recepients FROM broadcastlistsms b LEFT JOIN addcontact c ON b.id = c.broadcast_list_id 
WHERE (b.createdby_id = 1 and b.isdeleted = 0) and (c.createdby_id = 1 and c.isdeleted = 0)
GROUP BY b.id,b.brl_name;
```

In the future will have 3 more fields in the contact table like isdeleted, then also I need to check all of that 3 field and need a count value as per that field.

Here is the Fiddle link : [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYULH8tP5yVB18ffkJNvFe/6)

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Duplicate of [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097). PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search. PS Please format code reasonably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, please, provide the data in text format, or event better in a SQL Fiddle like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYULH8tP5yVB18ffkJNvFe/0

Try to organize your queries so that they can be more readable.

The problem was that you added the `Contact` conditions in the `WHERE`, by doing so, `Broadcast` will also be filtered, you must add all the `Contact` conditions in the `LEFT JOIN`.

To get the desired output you showed in the image (listing all broadcasts), you can't filter the broadcast:

```
SELECT b.id, 
       b.name, 
       COUNT(c.broadcast_Id) AS Recepients 
FROM Broadcast b 
LEFT JOIN Contact c ON b.id = c.broadcast_Id 
                   AND c.Created_by = 1 
                   AND c.isdeleted = 0
GROUP BY b.id,
         b.name
```

But to get the output you described (showing only what is not deleted and filtered by a specific user) is this:

```
SELECT b.id, 
       b.name, 
       COUNT(c.broadcast_Id) AS Recepients 
FROM Broadcast b 
LEFT JOIN Contact c ON b.id = c.broadcast_Id 
                   AND c.Created_by = 1 
                   AND c.isdeleted = 0
WHERE b.IsDeleted = 0 
  AND b.Created_by = 1
GROUP BY b.id,
         b.name
```