# Is it possible to join even though there is a null entry?

Tags: sql, join

I have two table that I am trying to join together. Proposed cost and Project. My join works as expected except for one entry where the Concept_ID_DFF (Project) used to join is null. Is there a way that I can join even though its blank.

Table  (Project)

| SRC_START_DTTM | Concept_ID_DFF |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-20 18:53:56.003 | NULL |
| 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150 | 300000005876166 |
| 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000 | 300000005876166 |

Table  (Proposal)

| CST_AMT | Concept_ID_DFF |
| --- | --- |
| 1262450.00 | 300000005876166 |
| 1510546.00 | 300000005876166 |
| 12874.00 | 300000005876166 |

Query Result

| ~Project | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23241 | 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150 | 1262450.00 |
| 23241 | 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150 | 1510546.00 |
| 23241 | 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150 | 12874.00 |
| 23241.0001 | 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000 | 1262450.00 |
| 23241.0001 | 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000 | 1510546.00 |
| 23241.0001 | 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000 | 12874.00 |

**In short for query result I want to see another 3 row that is with date 2021-09-20 18:53:56.003, but this is coming in null. Is there a way to have it be 300000005876166. I expect to see 23241, 23241.0001, and 23241.0002.**
Is there a way that I can fix my code to compensate for the null value?

```
SELECT  CONVERT(bigint, FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CONCEPT_MASTER_DSID) AS [~Proposal]
    ,   FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.VERSION AS [Cost Version]
    ,   DATEFROMPARTS(TRY_CONVERT(int, FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CST_YEAR), 1, 1) AS [~Reporting Period]
    ,   DIM_PRJ.SRC_START_DTTM
    ,   DIM_PRJ.PRJ_STAT_CD
    ,   DIM_PRJ.CONCEPT_ID_DFF
    ,   DIM_PRJ.DWID
    ,   CONVERT(float, (DIM_PRJ.DWID + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_PRJ.DWID, FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CST_AMT  ORDER BY DIM_PRJ.SRC_END_DTTM, TRY_CONVERT(bigint, DIM_PRJ.PRJ_STAT_CD))*.0001)) - .0001) AS [~Project]
    ,   TRY_CONVERT(int, FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CST_YEAR) AS [Cost Year]
    ,   FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CST_AMT AS [Proposed Cost] 
FROM Financial_Repository.FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Financial_Repository.DIM_PRJ_HISTORY DIM_PRJ
        ON DIM_PRJ.CONCEPT_ID_DFF = FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CONCEPT_MASTER_DSID
WHERE DIM_PRJ.DWID = '23241' AND [Version] = '1'
ORDER BY [~Project] ASC
```

Comment: Why is it null? Seems like it shouldn't be to me, the record of data is basically only a random date otherwise.

Comment: The Concept_ID_DFF is your only joining column but you could just add `or Concept_ID_DFF is null` to the join; you're removing the outer-joined rows anyway in the where clause.

Comment: What should happen when you have different values for `Concept_ID_DFF`?  When, i.e.,  this `Concept_ID_DFF` can also have the value `300000005876167` ?

Comment: Yeah concept_ID_DFF varies so the code wont work, Im just gonna have to figure out why its coming in null.

Comment: What does "coming in null" mean? "even though it's blank" What does that mean? If you mean it is (the value) null, say so.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. [A Q&A.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the ask you want it to default to 300000005876166 if null.  You could put a function into the join to default to 300000005876166 on the project ID DFF columns.

See join below

```
FROM Financial_Repository.FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Financial_Repository.DIM_PRJ_HISTORY DIM_PRJ
     ON ISNULL(DIM_PRJ.CONCEPT_ID_DFF, '300000005876166') = FACT_IM_TPE_PROPOSL_COST.CONCEPT_MASTER_DSID
```

Comment: If that is the case, yes.  But if there are other null entries, those too would get this value, which could be incorrect for the data (assuming that those entries should have their own `CONCEPT_ID_DFF` value).   But without knowing the data, there's no telling if that is the case or not.  But I would imagine it is...

Comment: Yeah that would only work for that once conceptID, but I have several. I agree, I should just try to figure out why its coming in as null. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CROSS JOIN`. For example:

```
select *
from project p
cross join proposal l
```

Result:

```
 SRC_START_DTTM           Concept_ID_DFF   SRC_START_DTTM  Concept_ID_DFF  
 ------------------------ ---------------- --------------- --------------- 
 2021-09-20 18:53:56.003  null             1262450.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150  300000005876166  1262450.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000  300000005876166  1262450.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-20 18:53:56.003  null             1510546.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150  300000005876166  1510546.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000  300000005876166  1510546.00      300000005876166 
 2021-09-20 18:53:56.003  null             12874.00        300000005876166 
 2021-09-20 18:54:22.150  300000005876166  12874.00        300000005876166 
 2021-09-23 14:02:49.000  300000005876166  12874.00        300000005876166
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EM1aVKXN).