# Snowflake - Left Join not working as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join

I'm looking to reconcile dates between two tables. In other words, I'm looking for where the date column is NULL from the right table.

The first query generates a table with sequence of dates between 2017-2022:

```
    select -1 + row_number() over(order by 0) i, start_date + i generated_date 
from (select '2017-01-01'::date start_date, '2022-12-31'::date end_date)
join table(generator(rowcount => 10000 )) x
qualify i < 1 + end_date - start_date
```

Sample of the table below:

| I | Generate_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 2017-01-02 |

The second query generates a tables generates with a date along with other items.

```
select distinct date
from table 
where i.id = id
```

Sample of the table below:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2021-01-01 |
| ID2 | 2017-01-02 |

I join both queries:

```
WITH calendar_table as (
select -1 + row_number() over(order by 0) i, start_date + i generated_date 
from (select '2017-01-01'::date start_date, '2022-12-31'::date end_date)
join table(generator(rowcount => 10000 )) x
qualify i < 1 + end_date - start_date)

select distinct t.generated_date, i.date
from calendar_table t 
left join table i on t.date = i.date
where i.id = 'id'
order by t.generated_date desc
```

I would expect the result to show this:

| Generated_date | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-02 |
| 2021-05-03 | NULL |

However, this is what appears. I thought a left join is supposed to bring back everything from the FROM clause. I know that 2021-05-03 exist in the left table. Can I please get suggestions on how to fix this?

| Generated_date | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-02 |
| 2021-05-04 | 2021-05-04 |
| 2021-05-05 | 2021-05-05 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing `LEFT JOIN` and later using `WHERE` with column from right part causes the query to behave as `INNER JOIN`:

```
from calendar_table t 
left join table i 
  on t.date = i.date
where i.id = 'id'    -- here
```

behaves as:

```
from calendar_table t 
inner join table i 
  on t.date = i.date
where i.id = 'id'    -- here
```

The `i.id = '...'` condition should be moved either as subquery or `ON` clause:

```
-- a)
from calendar_table t 
left join table i 
  on t.date = i.date
 and i.id = 'id'    

-- b)
from calendar_table t 
left join (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'id') AS i 
  on t.date = i.date
```

Comment: Hi @LukaszSzozda - how do you expand this to iterate over many IDs? I noticed if I put the id in the select clause, the ID column pulls back NULLs. That makes sense to me as the date doesn't exist. However, I need to iterate through many ids and see per ID which dates come back NULL.

Comment: @H.Hernandez `WHERE id IN ('id1', 'id2', ...)`

Comment: I understand that part but is there a way to force the id to show in the output even though the record is NULL?