# Selecting data with where exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, window-functions

I have three tables which i `LEFT JOIN`ed. In this case i needed to use `COALESCE(ID, ID1)` to replace missing IDs with ID1s.

The goal is to get just the IDs and all of their related data entries, given value 'w' in column OPS is present.

I tried using `EXISTS` clause but it just returns only rows where the value of column OPS is 'w' and not the other rows related to the same ID:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.age, t2.operation, t3.ops
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON COALESCE(t2.id, t2.id1) = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON COALESCE(t3.id, t3.id1) = t1.id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table3 
              WHERE id = t1.id
                AND (t3.ops = 'w'))
```

Now I try to figure out why my `EXISTS` clause does not work properly.

Data:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZU2hBlbCC)

This is the result i wanted to produce with the code:

| id | age | operation | ops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | A | q |
| 1 | 23 | A | w |
| 1 | 23 | A | e |
| 1 | 23 | B | q |
| 1 | 23 | B | w |
| 1 | 23 | B | e |
| 1 | 23 | C | q |
| 1 | 23 | C | w |
| 1 | 23 | C | e |
| 2 | 25 | A | q |
| 2 | 25 | A | w |
| 2 | 25 | B | q |
| 2 | 25 | B | w |
| 4 | 43 | A | q |
| 4 | 43 | A | w |
| 4 | 43 | B | q |
| 4 | 43 | B | w |

Comment: You are `LEFT JOIN`ing to `table3` (aliased as `t3`) but due to your `EXISTS` **require** that `t3.ops = 'w'`; that is *impossible* if there was no row in `table3` found. Is that intentional? Is so, why not use an `INNER JOIN` to `table3`?

Comment: On a different note, a clause like `COALESCE(t2.id, t2.id1) = t1.id` will be to detrimental to performance as the clause it not SARGable. If you need to do logic like this then use an `OR` as at least then the data engine has the opportunity to use an index: `t2.id = t1.id OR (t2.id IS NULL AND t2.id1 = t1.id)`

Comment: i used left join on t3 because i can see directly which OPS are related to OPERATION.

Comment: That doesn't address the point. If it's a `LEFT JOIN` *why* is it **required** that `ops` has a non-`NULL` value? By definition it is no longer a `LEFT JOIN` as (to repeat myself) it is **impossible** for `ops` to have a non-`NULL` value if no row in the table was found. Either the join to `table3` should be an `INNER JOIN` or the clause in the `EXISTS` is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: @Thom A Now i understand what you mean about the non-`NULL` values. The `EXISTS` clause was wrong, of course, because i didn't specify the connection at all.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for sharing the link. The question has already been answered.

Comment: I don't know why you think it matters that this has been answered. My comment was left by the system when I voted to suggest this as a duplicate. This post is here forever & the site goal is to be a collection of good Q&A & a zillionth unclear undebugged unresearched duplicate of a question is not helpful.  [tour] [ask] [help]

Comment: @philipxy I just wanted to say thank you and let you know that the question has been answered FOR ME. That was my only concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window function as specified by GMB will work, but also, I think there is a bit of confusion around using the EXISTS clause.

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.age, t2.operation, t3.ops
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON COALESCE(t2.id, t2.id1) = t1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON COALESCE(t3.id, t3.id1) = t1.id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM table3 inner_t3
  WHERE COALESCE(inner_t3.id, inner_t3.id1) = t1.id -- your join above wasn't 
                                                    -- on ID alone. This one 
                                                    -- shouldn't be either
  AND inner_t3.ops = 'w'  -- Make sure you have proper reference to inner 
                          -- table using alias.
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, I would recommend window functions rather than `exist` to check whether each  group has operation `w`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id AS t1id, 
        t1.age AS t1age, 
        t2.id AS t2id, 
        t2.id1 AS t2id1, 
        t2.operation AS t2operation, 
        t3.id AS t3id, 
        t3.id1 AS t3id1, 
        t3.ops AS t3ops,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t3.ops = 'w' then 1 else 0 end) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id) has_ops_w
    FROM table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON COALESCE(t2.id, t2.id1) = t1.id 
    LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON COALESCE(t3.id, t3.id1) = t1.id
) t
WHERE has_ops_w = 1
```

In [your DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QiJF7JdT):

| t1id | t1age | t2id | t2id1 | t2operation | t3id | t3id1 | t3ops | has_ops_w |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 | q | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 | A | *null* | 1 | w | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 | A | *null* | 1 | e | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | B | 1 | 1 | q | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | B | *null* | 1 | w | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | B | *null* | 1 | e | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | C | 1 | 1 | q | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | C | *null* | 1 | w | 1 |
| 1 | 23 | *null* | 1 | C | *null* | 1 | e | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 2 | A | 2 | 2 | q | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 2 | A | *null* | 2 | w | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 2 | B | 2 | 2 | q | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 2 | B | *null* | 2 | w | 1 |
| 4 | 43 | 4 | 4 | A | 4 | 4 | q | 1 |
| 4 | 43 | 4 | 4 | A | *null* | 4 | w | 1 |
| 4 | 43 | *null* | 4 | B | 4 | 4 | q | 1 |
| 4 | 43 | *null* | 4 | B | *null* | 4 | w | 1 |

Comment: I don't think the second left join accomplish anything once the filter is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand.
Here again is the `EXISTS` clause with the advice for better performance that @Thom A has given.
Further, @oglester gave an advice on the convention of names that helped a lot.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.age, t2.operation, t3.ops
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
  ON t2.id = t1.id OR (t2.id IS NULL AND t2.id1 = t1.id)
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 
  ON t3.id = t1.id OR (t3.id IS NULL AND t3.id1 = t1.id)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM table3 AS inner_t3 
  WHERE (inner_t3.id = t1.id OR (inner_t3.id IS NULL AND inner_t3.id1 = t1.id))
  AND inner_t3.ops = 'w'
);
```