# Filtering data at the end after doing double LEFT JOIN using this data from LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Got a tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    kid integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE keys (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    key varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    tid integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE terminals (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(64) NULL,
    ipaddr integer NOT NULL
);
```

Got a data:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, kid) VALUES ('jas', 'wedrowniczek', 1);
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, kid) VALUES ('mariusz', 'kolano', 2);
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, kid) VALUES ('ziobro', 'zbigniew', 3);
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, kid) VALUES ('kornel', 'makuszynski', 4);
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, kid) VALUES ('henryk', 'sienkiewicz', 5);

INSERT INTO keys (key, tid) VALUES ('key1', 1);
INSERT INTO keys (key, tid) VALUES ('key2', 2);
INSERT INTO keys (key, tid) VALUES ('key3', 3);
INSERT INTO keys (key, tid) VALUES ('key4', 4);
INSERT INTO keys (key, tid) VALUES ('key4', 5);

INSERT INTO terminals (name, ipaddr) VALUES ('pokoj1', 180879367);
INSERT INTO terminals (name, ipaddr) VALUES ('pokoj2', 180879468);
INSERT INTO terminals (name, ipaddr) VALUES ('pokoj3', 288704395);
INSERT INTO terminals (name, ipaddr) VALUES (NULL, 288703396);
INSERT INTO terminals (name, ipaddr) VALUES ('pokoj5', 0);
```

I need to get all the logins which have keys to terminal without descriptions or ipaddresses.

The results should be:

```
 id | firstname |   lastname   |  ipaddr   | name    |
----+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------
  4 | kornel    | makuszynski  | 288703396 |         |
  5 | henryk    | sienkiewicz  | 0         | pokoj5  |
```

My try:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, t.ipaddr, t.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN keys k ON (u.kid = k.id)
LEFT JOIN terminals t ON (t.id = k.tid)
WHERE
    t.ipaddr = 0
    OR t.name IS NULL;
```

It gives me empty result.

I understand that:
first is going SELECT then filtering is done using WHERE then LEFT JOIN.

...but is it possible to add some filtering at the end using data from LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Why do you need a `LEFT JOIN` here? An `INNER JOIN` would produce the result you expect.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/): make your example reproducible first.

Comment: What does "add some filtering at the end using data from LEFT JOIN" mean? This is not clear. PS [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097)

Comment: If I fix the table definitions so the DDL portional actually runs, then the SQL code produces the expected result. See it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/3M3JlE3i Therefore I must conclude the problem is incorrectly stated and have to vote to close until it's edited to be correct :( Also, based on the problem statement you probably still want INNER JOIN. You can see in the example link they still work as expected.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN terminals t ON t.id = k.tid and (t.ipaddr = 0 OR t.name IS NULL)`

Comment: I just did a mistake in column names in sql query on my test envirnoment . Many minutes I was googling. Then found Your answer whitch leads me to right answer. Thanks for Your time and engagement.

Answer (score 1):

When you created `terminals` you specified `NOT NULL` and then tried to insert name as `NULL`. Also, it's better practice to filter data before joining tables.

```
with t as (
select *
from   terminals 
where  ipaddr = 0 
   or  name is null 
)

select u.id 
      ,u.firstname 
      ,u.lastname   
      ,t.ipaddr   
      ,t.name    
from   users u join keys k using(id) join t on k.tid = t.id
```

| id | firstname | lastname | ipaddr | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | kornel | makuszynski | 288703396 | null |
| 5 | henryk | sienkiewicz | 0 | pokoj5 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h01fxzuC)