# PostgreSQL getting the count of distinct values after joining tables

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to get the proper count. I have 2 tables:

`Tbl1`

| id | name | call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaaaaa | 15 |
| 132 | bbbbb | 0 |

`Tbl2`

| id | involvement |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0 |
| 123 | 0 |
| 123 | 1 |

I would like to get the count of ids where `call = 15` and `involvement = 0`. My query:

```sql
select t1.id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.call=15 THEN 1 END) as calls
from Tbl1 t1 
  left join Tbl2 t2 
    on t2.id = t1.id 
where t2.involvement = 0;
```

The result expected for `count` is `1`.

Comment: Could you please format the question in a way that is easy to understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code was missing a `group by` to work.
2. With it added, you were counting all matching entries instead of distinct ones.
3. A `case` statement inside an aggregate function is emulating an [aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).
4. If columns used for `join` have matching names, you can list them in [`join...using(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):
5. Unless you double-quote your object names, they are [folded to lower case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.8.8.1), so `Tbl1` and `Tbl2` are actually `tbl1` and `tbl2`. Some ORM's, IDE's and clients can be set to auto-quote. For clarity, it's best to use the actual name the objects end up getting.

[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/ptDEsqrJ)

```sql
select count(distinct t2.id)     filter (where t1.call=15) as calls,
       array_agg(distinct t2.id) filter (where t1.call=15) as the_ids
from tbl1 t1 left join tbl2 t2 using(id)
where t2.involvement = 0;
```

If you also want to see a list of those distinct `id` that were counted, you can use the [`string_agg()` or `array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) shown above.

Check out [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) to format your questions and answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `exists`-based solution, because of 2 reasons:

- left join multiplicates `t1.id`s which must be "repaired" with `distinct` (unless `id` is not unique in `t1` itself - I assume it is a key)
- the intent is IMHO clearer for reader - it says *any* row with `involvement = 0` suffices for counting. (If - for example - the logic had to be changed to, say, having *only* `involvement = 0`, the condition would be easily changed to `all` or `not exists` operator but core of query would stay untouched.)

```sql
select count(t1.id)
from Tbl1 t1
where t1.call = 15
  and exists(select 1 from Tbl2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.involvemet = 0)
```