# how to retrive null data from Left Join in mysql when right table has no matching row?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables like these:
(Docs)

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc1 |
| 2 | Doc2 |

and

(Signs)

| Id | personId | docId | SignedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2023-01-02 |

So I want to get details of docs for each user. for instance  I need a list to show that user with Id = 1 like this:

(result)

| DocId | signedAt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | null |

I tried Left Join like below:

```
SELECT * from docs
LEFT JOIN Signs on docid = docs.id 
where Signs.personId = 1 || Signs.personId is null;
```

but it just returns the first line of the result table. how could I generate my desired result?

Comment: _"how could I generate my desired result?"_ - why do you have such a WHERE clause to begin with, when you apparently want the second row from your `Signs` table to add to the result?

Comment: So, I need this report only for person with id = 1 @CBroe

Comment: As I know simple join just will add the result with exactly matching. and left join will show the left table plus the matching rows in the right according to this definition https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_left_join.asp

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 With your typo fixed, your query works for me.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Comment: [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097) etc etc etc

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.signed_at
FROM docs t1
LEFT JOIN signs t2 ON t1.id = t2.doc_id AND t2.person_id = 1
```

Comment: It is absolutely the correct answer but why do I need to add that person_Id inside the ON clause?

Comment: Logically, your join condition is "I want all records where the doc ids match and the person id is 1". So this is good inside the ON clause. The semantics of left join will then also include all non-matching records, which are the remaining docs. It's just basic left join strategy really. Seems to me your original query works too ... once the typo is fixed.

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 Logic is simple. We filter only those rows where person_id = 1. Then we leftjoin this subset to docs table.