# Columns defined through if statement

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use an if statement to get a result like this:

```
SELECT 
IF(huxwz_user_orders.year = YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1, huxwz_user_orders.plannedweek + 52, huxwz_user_orders.plannedweek) as PlannedWeekG
```

When I used PlannedWeekG in my query like this: `WHERE PlannedWeekG > 0`

It's giving me an error "Unknown column 'PlannedWeekG' in where clause. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'HAVING' in place of 'WHERE' to look at the derived result. Since PlannedWeekG  is not a column in the DB, 'HAVING' is the magic to making this work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Having` clause in mysql:

```
SELECT 
IF(huxwz_user_orders.year = YEAR(CURDATE()) + 1, huxwz_user_orders.plannedweek + 52, huxwz_user_orders.plannedweek) as PlannedWeekG
HAVING PlannedWeekG > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the computed column `PlannedWeekG` on the `WHERE` clause since it still does not exist when the `WHERE` clause is processed.  You can use the `HAVING` clause as suggested in other answers or use your query as a derived table on another query that selects from the derived table.

Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596739/456712) answer, especially the part on Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement.