# Does inner join order and where as an impact on performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are these 2 queries equivalent in performance ?

```
select a.* 
from a 
inner join b 
    on a.bid = b.id 
inner join c 
    on b.cid = c.id 
where c.id = 'x'
```

and

```
select a.* 
from c  
inner join b 
    on b.cid = c.id 
join a 
    on a.bid = b.id 
where c.id = 'x'
```

Does it join all the table first then filter the condition, or is the condition applied first to reduce the join ?

(I am using sql server)

Comment: This could help: [Order Of Execution of the query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-query)

Comment: SQL server optimizer is generally smart enough to figure out the best sequence to use, so join table order is really not going to impact performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query Optimizer will almost always filter table `c` first before joining `c` to the other two tables. You can verify this by looking into the execution plan and see how many rows are being taken by SQL Server from table `c` to participate in the join.

**About join order**: the Query Optimizer will pick a join order that it thinks will work best for your query. It could be `a JOIN b JOIN (filtered c)` or `(filtered c) JOIN a JOIN b`.

If you want to force a certain order, include a hint:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        a
INNER JOIN  b  ON ...
INNER JOIN  c  ON ...
WHERE       c.id = 'x'
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

This will force SQL Server to do `a join b join (filtered c)`. **Standard warning**: unless you see massive performance gain, most times it's better to leave the join order to the Query Optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Read about http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

The execution order is FROM then WHERE, in this case or in any other cases I don't think the WHERE clause is executed before the JOINS .

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
from (select * from c where c.id = 'x') c
inner join b 
    on b.cid = c.id 
inner join a 
    on a.bid = b.id
```

This can create difference in execution.