# Possible positions and executing order about aggregation functions in select statement in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-function

Where can I put aggregation functions in one SQL query (in the `select` clause, in `having` clause or others ). And What's the executing order of aggregation functions in the logical processing order of the select statement?

The post "[Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-query)" there doesn't cover the functions' executing order.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can put subquery after Where ,from and middle of the sql statement.

```
//After Where   
 select * from orders where order_id in (select Oreder_id from OrderConfirmed)
// After From
 Select * from (select * from table) a
//Middle of sql Statement
 select id,(select Id from table1) form table2


 2) You Can put Aggregation function in both select clause and having clause.

    //In select
    select count(employee) from employees group by employee_dept
    //In having
    select count(employee) from employees group by employee_dept having(max(salary)>2000) 

3) order of execution of sql statement

  1)From 

  2)Where

  3)Group By

  4)Having

  5)aggregate Function

  6)Select
```

Comment: From the answer of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-query), you have a different order about `Having` and `Group By`.

Comment: Having executes before group by.

Comment: Are you sure? Based on my experience, I think `group by` executes before `having`.

Comment: sorry group by executes before having.